# Does Python have an ordered set?

Tags: python, set

Python has an [ordered dictionary](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/). What about an ordered set?

Comment: what about the converse, a bag of things?  (unordered and non-unique)

Comment: @wim `collections.Counter` is Python's bag.

Comment: What if something gets added twice? What should the position be?

Comment: @McKay - if it were to follow the behavior of collections.OrderDict it would still be in the position of the initial addition

Comment: Warning: several answers here are outdated. E.g., `dict` is now insertion-ordered (guaranteed since Python 3.7)

Comment: ^^+1 See a below answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657523/3559330. Dicts preserve order in Python 3.7+. Otherwise, use OrderedDict.

Comment: from sortedcontainers import Sorted*

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/

Comment: If you specifically want an ordered set in order to deduplicate a list, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214.

Comment: I've contributed to a discussion in the python discussion board in favor of adding `OrderedSet` to the standard `collections` library: https://discuss.python.org/t/add-orderedset-to-stdlib/12730.

Comment: This answer is excellent from a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7829569/257299

Comment: @McKay Mathematical and python sets are by definition "unordered collection[s] with no duplicate elements." If the data structure allowed duplicates then it would no longer be a set; it would be some other data structure. This question is more properly requesting a data structure (in python, more specifically a collection) that is mutable, ordered, and allows no duplicate elements, but it's easier to just phrase that as an ordered set and expect people know what you mean.

Comment: @chevydog yes, that's exactly my point. What the OP wants is not clear. Sets don't have an order, they want an order, so I think it's appropriate to ask what the order should be in certain cases.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

There is an [ordered set](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) (possible [new link](https://github.com/ActiveState/code/blob/3b27230f418b714bc9a0f897cb8ea189c3515e99/recipes/Python/576696_OrderedSet_with_Weakrefs/README.md)) recipe for this which is referred to from the [Python 2 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html). This runs on Py2.6 or later and 3.0 or later without any modifications. The interface is almost exactly the same as a normal set, except that initialisation should be done with a list.

```
OrderedSet([1, 2, 3])
```

This is a MutableSet, so the signature for `.union` doesn't match that of set, but since it includes `__or__` something similar can easily be added:

```
@staticmethod
def union(*sets):
    union = OrderedSet()
    union.union(*sets)
    return union

def union(self, *sets):
    for set in sets:
        self |= set
```

Comment: I selected my own answer because the reference from the documentation makes this close to an official answer

Comment: The interface is NOT exactly the same as the normal set object, many essential methods are missing such as `update`, `union`, `intersection`.

Comment: FYI, I noticed that a [slightly modified version](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/ordered-set) of the [recipe cited in this answer](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) has been [added to PyPi](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/ordered-set) as "ordered-set"

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not allowed to have two methods both called `union` in the same class.  The last one will "win" and the first one will fail to exist at runtime.  This is because `OrderedSet.union` (no parens) has to refer to a *single* object.

Comment: There is also "orderedset" package which is based on the same recipe but implemented in Cython -- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/orderedset .

Comment: See a below answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657523/3559330. Dicts preserve order in Python 3.7+. Otherwise, use OrderedDict.

Answer (score 390):

The answer is no, but as of Python 3.7 you can use the simple `dict` from the Python standard library with just keys (and values as `None`) for the same purpose.

Here's an example of how to use `dict` as an ordered set to filter out duplicate items while preserving order, thereby emulating an ordered set. Use the `dict` class method `fromkeys()` to create a dict, then simply ask for the `keys()` back.

```
>>> keywords = ['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz', 'foo']

>>> list(dict.fromkeys(keywords))
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

---

For older versions of Python, use the [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that this also works (faster) with vanilla `dict.fromkeys()`. But in that case, key order is only preserved in CPython 3.6+ implementations, so `OrderedDict` is a more portable solution when order matters.

Comment: @AnwarHossain `keys = (1,2,3,1,2,1)` `list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(keys).keys())` -> `[1, 2, 3]`, python-3.7. It works.

Comment: Can we infer that Set in Python 3.7+ preserve order too ?

Comment: This answers the actual question instead of jumping right into a work-around.

Comment: @user474491 Unlike `dict`, `set` in Python 3.7+ unfortunately does not preserve order.

Comment: `dict` is *not* guaranteed to preserve order. From the link, "The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied upon."

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Keep reading a little further on the same link: "Update December 2017: dicts retaining insertion order is guaranteed for Python 3.7"

Comment: The linked answer says `dict` retains **_insertion_** order, but it doesn't necessarily retain order after operations on its contents.  It also points out several features that `OrderedDict` has, but `dict` does not.  `dict` may be sufficient for the specific problem posed in this question, but one shouldn't take `dict`'s support for retaining insertion order to mean that it is a **_complete_** replacement for `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 173):

**Update**: This answer is obsolete as of Python 3.7. See [jrc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657523/74939) above for a better solution. Will keep this answer here only for historical reasons.

---

An ordered set is functionally a special case of an ordered dictionary.

The keys of a dictionary are unique. Thus, if one disregards the values in an ordered dictionary (e.g. by assigning them `None`), then one has essentially an ordered set.

As of Python [3.1](http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.1.html) and [2.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.7.html) there is [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). The following is an example implementation of an OrderedSet. (Note that only few methods need to be defined or overridden: `collections.OrderedDict` and [`collections.MutableSet`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#abcs-abstract-base-classes) do the heavy lifting.)

```
import collections

class OrderedSet(collections.OrderedDict, collections.MutableSet):

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            raise TypeError("update() takes no keyword arguments")

        for s in args:
            for e in s:
                 self.add(e)

    def add(self, elem):
        self[elem] = None

    def discard(self, elem):
        self.pop(elem, None)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return all(e in other for e in self)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self <= other and self != other

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return all(e in self for e in other)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self >= other and self != other

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'OrderedSet([%s])' % (', '.join(map(repr, self.keys())))

    def __str__(self):
        return '{%s}' % (', '.join(map(repr, self.keys())))
    
    difference = property(lambda self: self.__sub__)
    difference_update = property(lambda self: self.__isub__)
    intersection = property(lambda self: self.__and__)
    intersection_update = property(lambda self: self.__iand__)
    issubset = property(lambda self: self.__le__)
    issuperset = property(lambda self: self.__ge__)
    symmetric_difference = property(lambda self: self.__xor__)
    symmetric_difference_update = property(lambda self: self.__ixor__)
    union = property(lambda self: self.__or__)
```

Comment: @Casebash: yes, one may want to define a class `OrderedSet` which subclasses `OrderedDict` and `abc.Set` and then define `__len__`, `__iter__` and `__contains__`.

Comment: @Stephan202: Regrettably, the collection ABCs live in `collections`, but otherwise a good suggestion

Comment: @kaizer.se: right you are. I now posted an example implementation. Turns out my previous comment was not completely correct, but the posted code should speak for itself.

Comment: This is true, but you do have a lot of wasted space as a result, which  leads to suboptimal performance.

Comment: An addition; collections.OrderedDict is also available in python 2.7.

Comment: Doing `OrderedSet([1,2,3])` raises a TypeError. How does the constructor even work? Missing usage example.

Comment: This answer needs to be rewritten to: (1) support initialization using a list of tuple, (2) use `dict` (since it is now ordered) via composition rather than inheritance, and (3) use `collections.abc.MutableSet`.

Comment: `__sub__` etc are not normally defined. Needs to be imported or referenced differently.

Comment: How does this answer have so many upvotes? Did this work in Python 2? As @Torxed wrote, this results in `NameError: name '__sub__' is not defined` (Python 3.7 and 3.8).

Comment: @Socob I'm sure it worked back then. I haven't done any serious development in Python for many years now, so can't comment on the current state of this code, sorry.

Comment: @Stephan202 It still works, there's just some changes since Py2. But this is expected, as this is a bit niche and out of the ordinary development one would do :) Just left a comment to point people in the right direction, don't even remember how I fixed it hehe.

Comment: @Torxed OK, no, this didn’t work, not even in Python 2. Someone recently edited the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1653978/5), which broke the code. I’ve submitted an edit to revert this.

Comment: @Socob tnx! I approved your edit (minus the dropped empty line; stylistic preference ;) )

Comment: Gotta agree with @xApple here, I'm getting a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` when trying the most basic use-case of `OrderedSet([1, 3, 2])`

Answer (score 59):

### Implementations on PyPI

While others have pointed out that there is no built-in implementation of an insertion-order preserving set in Python (yet), I am feeling that this question is missing an answer which states what there is to be found on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org).

There  are the packages:

- [ordered-set](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordered-set/) (Python based)
- [collections-extended](https://pypi.org/project/collections-extended/)
- [boltons](https://pypi.org/project/boltons/) (under [setutils.IndexedSet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35258869/178013), Python-based)
- [oset](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oset/) (last updated in 2012)

Some of these implementations are based on the [recipe posted by Raymond Hettinger to ActiveState](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) which is also mentioned in other answers here.

#### Some differences

- ordered-set (version 1.1)
- advantage: O(1) for lookups by index (e.g. `my_set[5]`)
- oset (version 0.1.3)
- advantage: O(1) for `remove(item)`
- disadvantage: apparently O(n) for lookups by index

Both implementations have O(1) for `add(item)` and `__contains__(item)` (`item in my_set`).

Comment: A new contender is [collections_extended.setlist](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28052907/1031434). Functions like `set.union` don't work on it though, even though it inherits `collections.abc.Set`.

Comment: `OrderedSet` now supports [`remove`](http://orderedset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orderedset.html#orderedset.OrderedSet.remove)

Comment: There is also `SortedSet` from sortedcontainers 2.3.0 with a bunch of other sorted stuff.

Answer (score 53):

I can do you one better than an OrderedSet: boltons has [a pure-Python, 2/3-compatible `IndexedSet` type](http://boltons.readthedocs.org/en/latest/setutils.html) that is not only an ordered set, but also supports indexing (as with lists).

Simply `pip install boltons` (or copy `setutils.py` into your codebase), import the `IndexedSet` and:

```
>>> from boltons.setutils import IndexedSet
>>> x = IndexedSet(list(range(4)) + list(range(8)))
>>> x
IndexedSet([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> x - set(range(2))
IndexedSet([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> x[-1]
7
>>> fcr = IndexedSet('freecreditreport.com')
>>> ''.join(fcr[:fcr.index('.')])
'frecditpo'
```

Everything is unique and retained in order. Full disclosure: I wrote the `IndexedSet`, but that also means [you can bug me if there are any issues](https://github.com/mahmoud/boltons/issues).

Comment: Indexing does not work when negative indexes are supplied. For instance, this s[-4:-1] returns IndexedSet([]) on a very non-empty set.

Comment: @darlove Not sure what version you're on but negative indexes are supported and your supplied case does not reproduce on the issue you opened: https://github.com/mahmoud/boltons/issues/274

Answer (score 28):

If you're using the ordered set to maintain a sorted order, consider using a sorted set implementation from PyPI. The [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) module provides a [SortedSet](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html) for just this purpose. Some benefits: pure-Python, fast-as-C implementations, 100% unit test coverage, hours of stress testing.

Installing from PyPI is easy with pip:

```
pip install sortedcontainers
```

Note that if you can't `pip install`, simply pull down the sortedlist.py and sortedset.py files from the [open-source repository](https://github.com/grantjenks/sorted_containers).

Once installed you can simply:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet
help(SortedSet)
```

The sortedcontainers module also maintains a [performance comparison](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) with several alternative implementations.

For the comment that asked about Python's bag data type, there's alternatively a [SortedList](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html) data type which can be used to efficiently implement a bag.

Comment: Note that the `SortedSet` class there requires members to be comparable and hashable.

Comment: @gsnedders The builtins `set` and `frozenset` also require elements to be hashable. The comparable constraint is the addition for `SortedSet`, but it's also an obvious constraint.

Comment: As the name suggests, this does not maintain order. It is nothing but sorted(set([sequence])) which makes better?

Comment: @ldmtwo I'm not sure which you're referring to but just to be clear, [SortedSet](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html) as part of [Sorted Containers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) does maintain sorted order.

Comment: @GrantJ - It is the difference between whether it maintains _insertion_ order or _sort_ order. Most of the other answers are regarding insertion order. I think you are already aware of this based on your first sentence, but it's probably what ldmtwo is saying.

Comment: This one is available by default on leetcode

Answer (score 17):

As other answers mention, as for python 3.7+, the `dict` is ordered by definition. Instead of subclassing `OrderedDict` we can subclass `abc.collections.MutableSet` or `typing.MutableSet` using the `dict`'s keys to store our values.

```py
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T")


class OrderedSet(typing.MutableSet[T]):
    """A set that preserves insertion order by internally using a dict."""

    def __init__(self, iterable: typing.Iterable[T]):
        self._d = dict.fromkeys(iterable)

    def add(self, x: T) -> None:
        self._d[x] = None

    def discard(self, x: T) -> None:
        self._d.pop(x, None)

    def __contains__(self, x: object) -> bool:
        return self._d.__contains__(x)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self._d.__len__()

    def __iter__(self) -> typing.Iterator[T]:
        return self._d.__iter__()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{{{', '.join(str(i) for i in self)}}}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<OrderedSet {self}>"
```

Then just:

```py
x = OrderedSet([1, 2, -1, "bar"])
x.add(0)
assert list(x) == [1, 2, -1, "bar", 0]
```

[I added this code, with some tests, in a small library](https://github.com/bustawin/ordered-set-37), so anyone can just `pip install` it.

Comment: Don't use this as-is.  `discard` should never ever raise a `KeyError`.  Also note that this doesn't provide a sensible `__repr__`

Comment: @JasonForbes You are right —in fact we addressed your comments in the linked repo. So I just brought those fixes in this answer. Thank you for pointing it out! :-)

Answer (score 12):

In case you're already using pandas in your code, its `Index` object behaves pretty like an ordered set, as shown in [this article](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/introducing-pandas-objects).

Examples from the article:

```
indA = pd.Index([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
indB = pd.Index([2, 3, 5, 7, 11])

indA & indB  # intersection
indA | indB  # union
indA - indB  # difference
indA ^ indB  # symmetric difference
```

Comment: Can you include an example in this answer? Links tend to be broken after some time.

Comment: for the difference between sets, you actually need to use `indA.difference(indB)`, the minus sign performs standard subtraction

Comment: It's important to note that `pd.Index` allows for duplicate elements, which one would not expect from an actual Python `set`.

Answer (score 10):

A little late to the game, but I've written a class `setlist` as part of `collections-extended` that fully implements both `Sequence` and `Set`

```
>>> from collections_extended import setlist
>>> sl = setlist('abracadabra')
>>> sl
setlist(('a', 'b', 'r', 'c', 'd'))
>>> sl[3]
'c'
>>> sl[-1]
'd'
>>> 'r' in sl  # testing for inclusion is fast
True
>>> sl.index('d')  # so is finding the index of an element
4
>>> sl.insert(1, 'd')  # inserting an element already in raises a ValueError
ValueError
>>> sl.index('d')
4
```

GitHub: https://github.com/mlenzen/collections-extended

Documentation: http://collections-extended.lenzm.net/en/latest/

PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collections-extended

Answer (score 10):

There's no `OrderedSet` in official library.
I make an exhaustive cheatsheet of all the data structure for your reference.

```
DataStructure = {
    'Collections': {
        'Map': [
            ('dict', 'OrderDict', 'defaultdict'),
            ('chainmap', 'types.MappingProxyType')
        ],
        'Set': [('set', 'frozenset'), {'multiset': 'collection.Counter'}]
    },
    'Sequence': {
        'Basic': ['list', 'tuple', 'iterator']
    },
    'Algorithm': {
        'Priority': ['heapq', 'queue.PriorityQueue'],
        'Queue': ['queue.Queue', 'multiprocessing.Queue'],
        'Stack': ['collection.deque', 'queue.LifeQueue']
        },
    'text_sequence': ['str', 'byte', 'bytearray']
}
```

Comment: Some odd things in this cheatsheet: according to [collections.abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), Sequences are Collections, not a sibling. And iterator does not support indexing, so shouldn't be on the same group as lists and tuples. Also, all text_sequences are also Sequence

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, `OrderedDict` is a superset of an ordered set in terms of functionality, but if you need a set for interacting with an API and *don't* need it to be mutable, `OrderedDict.keys()` is actually an implementation `abc.collections.Set`:

```
import random
from collections import OrderedDict, abc

a = list(range(0, 100))
random.shuffle(a)

# True
a == list(OrderedDict((i, 0) for i in a).keys())

# True
isinstance(OrderedDict().keys(), abc.Set)
```

The caveats are immutability and having to build up the set like a dict, but it's simple and only uses built-ins.

Answer (score 2):

The [ParallelRegression](https://github.com/rcbellamy/ParallelRegression) package provides a [setList( )](https://parallel-regression.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ParallelRegression.html#setlist) ordered set class that is more method-complete than the options based on the ActiveState recipe.  It supports all methods available for lists and most if not all methods available for sets.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [pip library](https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/) that does this:

```sh
pip install ordered-set
```

Then you can use it:

```py
from ordered_set import OrderedSet
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `pd.unique` from `pandas` - does exactly what you need!

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.unique([3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 2])
array([3, 1, 4, 5, 2])
```

Answer (score -2):

This answer is for completeness sake. If the length of your `set` is small, and your code is single-threaded, a `list` could work just fine as it's implicitly ordered.

```
if not new_item in my_list:
    my_list.append(new_item)
```

If using this approach:

- To append or remove an item, first check for presence as in the code above.
- To compare equality, use `set(my_list)`.

Checking for presence in a list of course has an O(n) complexity, but this could be acceptable for a small list, especially if high performance isn't required.

Comment: The main issue with this approach is that adding runs in O(n). Meaning it gets slower with big lists. Python's built-in sets are very good at making adding elements faster. But for simple use-cases, it certainly does work!

Comment: This answer should not be deleted because this approach works acceptably for small lists where the best performance isn't required.

Answer (score -6):

For many purposes simply calling sorted will suffice.  For example

```
>>> s = set([0, 1, 2, 99, 4, 40, 3, 20, 24, 100, 60])
>>> sorted(s)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 24, 40, 60, 99, 100]
```

If you are going to use this repeatedly, there will be overhead incurred by calling the sorted function so you might want to save the resulting list, as long as you're done changing the set.  If you need to maintain unique elements and sorted, I agree with the suggestion of using OrderedDict from collections with an arbitrary value such as None.

Comment: The purpose for OrderedSet is to be able to get the items in the order which they where added to the set. You example could maybe called SortedSet...