# Efficient processing of email list in Python

Tags: python, performance, list, iterator

I have a very long list of emails that I would like to process to:

1. separate good emails from bad emails, and
2. remove duplicates but keep all the non-duplicates in the same order.

This is what I have so far:

```
email_list = ["joe@example.com", "invalid_email", ...]
email_set = set()
bad_emails = []
good_emails = []
dups = False
for email in email_list:
    if email in email_set:
        dups = True
        continue
    email_set.add(email)
    if email_re.match(email):
        good_emails.append(email)
    else:
        bad_emails.append(email)
```

I would like this chunk of code to be as fast as possible, and of less importance, to minimize memory requirements.  Is there a way to improve this in Python?  Maybe using list comprehensions or iterators?

EDIT: Sorry!  Forget to mention that this is Python 2.5 since this is for GAE.

email_re is from django.core.validators

Comment: You can run it using cProfile to see what is taking all the time if you're not sure where the bottleneck is.

Comment: It's pretty likely that whatever regex you're using is the bottleneck here. Care to post it? is it compiled?

Comment: @jozzas, he is using it like: `email_re.match(email)`, it's only valid when email_re is a compiled regex.

Answer (score 2):

Look at: [Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set) , and select an implementation you like.

So just:

```
email_list = OrderedSet(["joe@example.com", "invalid_email", ...])

bad_emails = [] 
good_emails = []

for email in email_list:
    if email_re.match(email):
        good_emails.append(email)
    else:
        bad_emails.append(email)
```

Probably is the fastest and simpliest solution you can achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any way to speed up what you have.  It's fast to use a `set` to keep track of things, and it's fast to use a `list` to store a list.

I like the `OrderedSet` solution, but I doubt a Python implementation of `OrderedSet` would be faster than what you wrote.

You could use an `OrderedDict` to solve this problem.  But that was added for Python 2.7.  You could use a recipe (like: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/) to add `OrderedDict` but again I don't think it would be any faster than what you have.

I'm trying to think of a Python module that is implemented in C to solve this problem.  I think that's the only hope of beating your code.  But I haven't thought of anything.

If you can get rid of the `dups` flag, it will be faster simply by running less Python code.

Interesting question.  Good luck.