# Removing duplicate strings from a list in python

Tags: python, string

If I have a string list ,

```
a = ["asd","def","ase","dfg","asd","def","dfg"]
```

how can I remove the duplicates from the list?

Comment: Check this answer if you want to preserve order: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657523/3107708

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Convert to a set:

```
a = set(a)
```

Or optionally back to a list:

```
a = list(set(a))
```

Note that this doesn't preserve order. If you want to preserve order:

```
seen = set()
result = []
for item in a:
    if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item)
        result.append(item)
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/p9yJU)

Answer (score 16):

Use the set type to remove duplicates

```
a = list(set(a))
```

Answer (score 6):

You could pop 'em into a `set` and then back into a list:

```
a = [ ... ]
s = set(a)
a2 = list(s)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def getUniqueItems(iterable):
result = []
for item in iterable:
    if item not in result:
        result.append(item)
return result

print (''.join(getUniqueItems(list('apple'))))
```

P.S. Same thing like one of the answers here but a little change, set is not really required !

Comment: does this code snippet preserve the order?

Comment: It does preserve order, but has quadratic complexity, and that is bad for any list remotely big.

Comment: this awesome! thanks