# How to get rid of repetitive elements in a Python list?

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

I have list of integers in Python. Some of the values are present several times in the list. What is an elegant way to get list out of first list, where each element is presented once?

Comment: search, please.  This has been asked numerous times.

Comment: @RikPoggi your link is not pointing a duplicate of this question :-)

Comment: This isn't quite a duplicate of the above, because the above concerns order. Here's a true duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8200342/

Answer (score 3):

One nice way that isn't guaranteed to maintain the ordering:

```
l = list(set(l))
```

Answer (score 1):

`list(set(your_list))`

But if you don't want duplicates, maybe you should be using a set instead of a list in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Using *[set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set)*:

```
dup_list = (1,2,2,3,3,3)
cleaned_list = list(set(dup_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.groupby` ( http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby ).

From the docs: `[k for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')] --> A B C D A B`

You will likely wish to use `sorted` also.