# Sorting model fields in set

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm using [this django snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2020/), which exports data to csv file from the admin. It has these two lines that get field names from the model.

```
    opts = modeladmin.model._meta
    field_names = set([field.name for field in opts.fields])
```

However, these field names are not in order. Is there a way to sort by their order of declaration in their model? If not, order a set by alphabetical order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No. A set will remove any ordering.

If you want to order by alphabetical order, convert it to a list and call sort() on it.

```
field_names = list(field_names)
field_names.sort()
```

---

You could check out a few other stack answers to implement an ordered set which will work with the rest of the code (the `set & set`):

[Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)

---

Or replace the code that uses sets with those that use lists:

```
field_names = [field.name for field in opts.fields]
if fields:
    field_names = filter(lambda field: field in fields, field_names)
elif exclude:
    field_names = filter(lambda field: field not in exclude, field_names)
```

I don't see why a model would ever have multiple fields of the same name, and I don't see any worthwhile performance gain from using a set for a 10 item set for a periodic admin action, so you might as well remove them.