# Best way to eliminate duplicates in a list, but keep previous relative order

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)
>   [Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)

I find myself doing the following quite frequently:

```
list_of_items # I have a list of items
set(list_of_items) # I want to remove duplicates
```

However, in converting to a `set`, I lose the initial ordering I had in the list, which is important.

What is the best way to remove duplicates in a list AND keep the initial (relative) ordering of the list?

Comment: Definitely a duplicate.  One of the answers is also a near duplicate of the answer from the duplicate question @Levon mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is somewhat of an abuse of list comprehensions, but:

```
seen = set()
item_list = [seen.add(item) or item for item in item_list if item not in seen]
```

Comment: What does the  `or item` do in the left side of the comprehension?

Comment: `seen.add(item)` returns `None` so `or item` makes the expression evaluate to `item`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to remove duplicates, use the data as keys and anything as values. If it's in the dict, don't add it again.

```
d = dict()
for i in range(0, len(list_of_items)):
    if(list_of_items[i] not in d):
        d[list_of_items[i]] = i
        list_of_items2.append(list_of_items[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly hackish, but ...

```
item_list = [x[1] for x in sorted(x[::-1] for x in dict(zip(item_list[::-1],range(len(item_list)))).items())][::-1]
```