# A way to store primes in python (i.e. have a list that checks if a element is there, and that can output elements in order)

Tags: python

I want to store a list of primes, in a way that both allows me to iterate over it (in order) and to check quickly if a given prime is there.

What is the best way ?

Should I just use a list? In this case, I suppose that there is a builtin for binary search. What is it ?

Should I use both a list and a set ? I know this works from the point of view of efficiency, but I'd like a way that is a bit less messy ...

Comment: Is it relevant that they are primes, or is that only incidental?  And if it is relevant, is there a reason not to just have an infinite primes detector?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an ordered set

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set#1653974

Comment: Although, for a finite set of (sorted) numbers, a binary-search over a simple list may also have desirable/sufficient characteristics ..

Comment: @sr2222 : not incidental. I am dealing with this right now.
I am not sure what you mean, though. A function that tests for primality ?

Answer (score 0):

If ordered sets sound overkill for doubling the storage, you can keep the list and use the [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) module for O(log n) lookups. It does binary search on sorted lists.