# remove duplicates using set on zip lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to learn python, especially lists, and I have a small problem. I have two lists:

```
alist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3]
blist=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","a","b","c"]
```

what I's like to do is remove duplicates from "both the lists". i.e only when an element of alist and its corresponding element in blist (in pairs) are the same, I delete them. I am expecting an outcome, looking like:

```
alist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
blist=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]
```

So, I try to first do a set on the zip:

```
kk=set(zip(alist,blist))
```

and then do:

```
alist[:],blist[:]=zip(*kk)
```

then I get:

```
alist=[5, 6, 4, 7, 3, 8, 2, 1, 9]
blist=['e', 'f', 'd', 'g', 'c', 'h', 'b', 'a', 'i']
```

as you can see, the order is not maintained. I was wondering if it was possible somehow to use "sorted" and "index" to get the lists in correct order. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

The python version is 2.7.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for this:

```
In [16]: d = collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(zip(alist, blist))

In [17]: [k[0] for k in d]
Out[17]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [18]: [k[1] for k in d]
Out[18]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

An [ordered set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set) -- if it were available -- would perhaps lead to an even cleaner solution.

Comment: I think you were on the right track with your now removed ordered set suggestion.  It seems a fairly wasteful hack to create an ordereddict just so you can get an ordered set via the keys.

Comment: @sr2222: Since you think the remark was useful, I've reinstated it.

Comment: @NPE: thanks a lot for this. However, I do not understand what you do when you do: [k[0] for k in d] Also, is this solution valid for python 2.7? .. going to try this now!

Comment: The soluton does work brilliantly.. but I am not entirely sure what [k[0] for k in d] and [k[1] for k in d] does in this case. I would appreciate if you could explain this a bit!

Comment: @JohnJ: Here, `k` iterates over every key in `d`, and `k[0]` simply extracts the first component of `k` (similarly for `k[1]`).

Comment: @NPE: How about this? d=collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(zip(alist, blist)).keys() and then simply alist[:],blist[:]=zip(*d)

Comment: @JohnJ: I haven't tried it, but it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 1):

use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
In [1]: alist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3]
In [2]: blist=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","a","b","c"]

In [3]: from collections import OrderedDict
In [6]: od = OrderedDict().fromkeys(zip(alist, blist))

In [7]: od
Out[7]: OrderedDict([((1, 'a'), None), ((2, 'b'), None), ((3, 'c'), None), ((4, 'd'), None), ((5, 'e'), None), ((6, 'f'), None), ((7, 'g'), None), ((8, 'h'), None), ((9, 'i'), None)])
```

Comment: I think this does something different to what OP is asking. If two elements of `alist` are the same, but the corresponding elements of `blist` differ, this would only keep one pair and not both.

Comment: yeah,... you are absolutely right, I'll fix my answer -- Thanks!

Comment: but how fixing without copying your solution?? Can I retreat my answer??