# Appending an id to a list if not already present in the list

Tags: python

I am trying to check if id is in a list and append the  id only if its not in the list using the below code..however I see that the id is getting appended even though id is already present in the list.. can anyone provide inputs on what is wrong here?

```
   list = ['350882 348521 350166\r\n']
    id = 348521
    if id not in list:
        list.append(id)
    print list

OUTPUT:-
['350882 348521 350166\r\n', 348521]
```

Comment: Your id is a part of the string, that is why the value is appended. `348521` is not equal to that string.

Comment: Why the weird list contents? a) they're strings, b) there seem to be multiple ids in one element. I would suggest you canonicalized your data structure first.

Comment: @NilsWerner - how to check if an id is already present in one element which contains multiple ids

Comment: Change your data structrure first.

Comment: @NilsWerner - it cannot be changed

Comment: Just as a warning - both `id` and `list` are already used by the standard library. If you overwrite them, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @user2341103 What are your real constraints? That data structure can be changed. You're doing that with `.append()`. Tell us what you want to achieve as a result: values concatenated again into a string? Do you have multiple strings in the list? Something else?

Answer (score 115):

What you are trying to do can almost certainly be achieved with a set.

```
>>> x = set([1,2,3])
>>> x.add(2)
>>> x
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> x.add(4)
>>> x.add(4)
>>> x
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>>
```

using a set's add method you can build your unique set of ids very quickly. Or if you already have a list

```
unique_ids = set(id_list)
```

as for getting your inputs in numeric form you can do something like

```
>>> ids = [int(n) for n in '350882 348521 350166\r\n'.split()]
>>> ids
[350882, 348521, 350166]
```

Comment: But set is unordered. If OP wants to maintain the original order of the list this won't work.

Comment: You are correct, if any future visitors need to maintain the order they may consider some implementation of an [ordered set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set).

Comment: original order will be lost in case something like this is done using a set.

Comment: A better way of doing what you mentioned in the last step is : `ids = list(map(int,input.rstrip().split()))`

Comment: @DhirajGandhi [it seems most people consider list comprehensions more readable than the functional approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/322909) (the functional approach is slightly faster). You shouldn't use variable names that collide with the build-ins, which is what's going on with `input`. The call to `.rstrip` is not needed as `.split` already removes the "whitespace" characters. I don't think I'd call your code better ... maybe faster at the cost of readable.

Answer (score 46):

A more pythonic way, without using set is as follows:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lst.append(3) if 3 not in lst else lst
```

Comment: This is a misuse of a conditional expression. Just use a normal if-statement: `if 3 not in lst: lst.append(3)`

Comment: Also this answer suggests `lst.append(3)` would return something other than `None`. I agree with @wjandrea to use a normal if-statement instead or `[*lst, 3] if 3 not in lst else lst`

Comment: The ternary is strange since you're not assigning it.  I agree that a standard if statement is cleaner. At the very least I would make it `lst.append(3) if 3 not in lst else None` since the append() returns NoneType. That at least would give consistency if someone tried to assign this to a variable.

Answer (score 10):

There are a couple things going on with your example. You have a list containing a string of numbers and newline characters:

```py
list = ['350882 348521 350166\r\n']
```

And you are trying to find a number ID within this list:

```py
id = 348521
if id not in list:
    ...
```

Your first conditional is always going to pass, because it will be looking for integer `348521` in `list` which has one element at index `list[0]` with the string value of `'350882 348521 350166\r\n'`, so integer 348521 will be added to that list, making it a list of two elements: a string and an integer, as your output shows.

To reiterate: *list is searched for id, not the string in list's first element.*

If you were trying to find if the string representation of `'348521'` was contained within the larger string contained within your list, you could do the following, noting that you would need to do this for each element in `list`:

```py
if str(id) not in list[0]: # list[0]: '350882 348521 350166\r\n'
    ...                    #                  ^^^^^^
```

However be aware that you would need to wrap `str(id)` with whitespace for the search, otherwise it would also match:

```
2348521999
 ^^^^^^
```

It is unclear whether you want your "list" to be a "string of integers separated by whitespace" or if you really want a list of integers.

If all you are trying to accomplish is to have a list of IDs, and to add IDs to that list only if they are not already contained, (and if the order of the elements in the list is ***not important***,) then a set would be the best data structure to use.

```py
ids = set(
    [int(id) for id in '350882 348521 350166\r\n'.strip().split(' ')]
)

# Adding an ID already in the set has no effect
ids.add(348521)
```

If the ordering of the IDs in the string ***is important*** then I would keep your IDs in a standard list and use your conditional check:

```py
ids = [int(id) for id in '350882 348521 350166\r\n'.strip().split(' ')]

if 348521 not in ids:
    ...
```

Answer (score 9):

7 years later, allow me to give a one-liner solution by building on a previous answer. You could do the followwing:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
```

to Add `[3, 4, 5]` into `numbers` without repeating `3`, do the following:

```
numbers = list(set(numbers + [3, 4, 5]))
```

This results in `4` and `5` being added to `numbers` as in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

**Explanation**:

Now let me explain what happens, starting from the inside of the `set()` instruction, we took `numbers` and added `3`, `4`, and `5` to it which makes `numbers` look like `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]`.
Then, we took that (`[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]`) and transformed it into a set which gets rid of duplicates, resulting in the following `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. Now since we wanted a list and not a set, we used the function `list()` to make that set (`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`) into a list, resulting in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` which we assigned to the variable `numbers`

This, I believe, will work for all types of data in a list, and objects as well if done correctly.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is a general solution. this question's particular case, given that the ids are in a string, one could separate them by `' '` to get a list of strings corresponding each to an id, then stripping the special characters from the last id and apply the solution I gave.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with other answers that you are doing something weird here. You have a list containing a string with multiple entries that are themselves integers that you are comparing to an integer id.

This is almost surely not what you should be doing. You probably should be taking input and converting it to integers before storing in your list. You could do that with:

```
input = '350882 348521 350166\r\n'
list.append([int(x) for x in input.split()])
```

Then your test will pass. If you really are sure you don't want to do what you're currently doing, the following should do what you want, which is to not add the new id that already exists:

```
list = ['350882 348521 350166\r\n']
id = 348521
if id not in [int(y) for x in list for y in x.split()]:
    list.append(id)
print list
```

Comment: is "int(y) for x in list for y in x.split()" a valid one?

Comment: @user - yes that should be valid. It looks weird, I know. The "for" loops should be read in the order they're written. Then you take whatever is before the for loop as the result.

Answer (score 2):

Your list just contains a string.  Convert it to integer IDs:

```
L = ['350882 348521 350166\r\n']

ids = [int(i) for i in L[0].strip().split()]
print(ids)
id = 348521
if id not in ids:
    ids.append(id)
print(ids)
id = 348522
if id not in ids:
    ids.append(id)
print(ids)
# Turn it back into your odd format
L = [' '.join(str(id) for id in ids) + '\r\n']
print(L)
```

Output:

```
[350882, 348521, 350166]
[350882, 348521, 350166]
[350882, 348521, 350166, 348522]
['350882 348521 350166 348522\r\n']
```

Comment: I want to maintain them as strings

Comment: Update your question with your desired output.  We aren't mind readers!

Comment: @user2341103, It looks like you read the values from a file.  Just write it back out joined back into strings.  Updated answer with example.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to change your structure, or at least create a copy of it containing the same data (e.g. make a class property with a setter and getter that read from/write to that string behind the scenes), then you can use a regular expression to check if an item is in that "list" at any given time, and if not, append it to the "list" as a separate element.

`if not re.match("\b{}\b".format(348521), some_list[0]): some_list.append(348521)`

This is probably faster than converting it to a set every time you want to check if an item is in it. But using `set` as others have suggested here is a million times better.

Answer (score -2):

Your id variable is a number where your list only has one element.  It's a string that contains your other IDs.  You either need to check if id is in that string, or pull the numbers out of the string and store them in the list separately

```
list  = [350882, 348521, 350166]
```