# Appending unique part of string to list

Tags: python, list

I have following code from which I expect the output as : ['abcdef'] ['def'].
I want the a2 list to contain unique elements of a1 that are not present in variable x.

```
>>> a1=[]
>>> a2=[]
>>> a1.append("abcdef")
>>> x="abc"
>>> if x not in a1:
...     a2.append(a1)
... 
>>> print a1, a2
['abcdef'] [['abcdef']]
```

Any help is appreciated.

- This question is NOT a duplicate of
  [Appending an id to a list if not already present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370984/appending-an-id-to-a-list-if-not-already-present) . My question deals with appending a substring.

Comment: You should add some better examples, currently it's not clear what you're doing here.

Comment: I think Omer's answer below is correct. The `unique elements of ...` points to that. If so, you should know that _substring_ is the wrong word for it. You're looking at strings as sets of characters. And, I'm getting `['abcdef']` and `[]` from your code since the `if` statement is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work. you need to compare each letters one by one then append them to a new string

```
a1=[]
a2=[]
a1.append("abcdef")
x="abc"
y = "abcdef"
new = ""
for letter in y:
    if letter not in x:
        new = new + letter

a2.append(new)

print a1, a2
```

output:

```
['abcdef'] ['def']
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

this version will check each item in the list vs a single string to check if the string is in any of those

```
a1=[]
a2=[]
a1.append("abcdef")
x="abc"
new = ""
for item in a1:
    for letter in item:
        if letter not in x:
            new = new + letter

a2.append(new)

print a1, a2
```

Comment: Nice interpreting of the question. I did not get this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really only care about *unique* letters, you can do this very easily using sets:

```
>>> set('abcdef') - set('def')
{'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

If you need the answer as a string, then you can do `''.join(set('abcdef') - set('def')`.

Note that this doesn't keep the elements in any particular order (they *happen* to be alphabetical here, but the internal order of a set is arbitrary).