# Best Pythonic way to conditionally append lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm sure this question has come up before, but I couldn't find an exact example.

I have 2 lists and want to append the second to the first, only of the values are not already there.

So far I have working code, but was wondering if there were a better, more "Pythonic" was of doing this:

```
>>> list1
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list2
[2, 4]
>>> list1.extend([x for x in list2 if x not in list1])
>>> list1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**EDIT**
Based on comments made, this code does not satisfy adding only once, ie:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list2 = [2,4,4,4]
>>> list1.extend([x for x in list2 if x not in list1])
>>> list1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

How would I end up with only:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Normally, you'd use sets to maintain unique values.

Comment: Does the order of the elements matter?

Comment: What if `list2` is `[2, 4, 4]`?

Comment: If `list1` is `[1,1,2,3]` and `list2` is `[2,4,4]`, what is the expected output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python have an ordered set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way could be using built in type [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=frozenset#set):

```
list(set(list1).union(list2))
```

You would need to store the result of the operation, if you wanted to *extend* `list1` then you can assign it to `list1`:

```
list1=list(set(list1).union(list2))
```

Note: Keep in mind that this approach may not keep the order of the elements in the list.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `list(set(list1).union(list2))` would avoid building an intermediary list object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is there a different between the two? I mean, I know the difference but is it relevant?

Comment: Both this answer and @thefourtheye 's answer work. I would go for this one as it doesn't require an additional import.

Comment: The actual answer is: list1 = list(set(list1).union(list2))

Comment: @ardochhigh Seems so, since the user was aiming for `extend`

Comment: @PauloBu: `set(list1 + list2)` builds an intermediary list object, `set(list1).union(list2)` builds an intermediary set object, but it'll be smaller.

Comment: @ardochhigh before ticking the answer, please check if the output of this answer is good for you, if the input is `list1, list2 = [100, 200, 300], [200, 400]`

Comment: @thefourtheye I made a note about it in the answer as well just to prevent the OP.

Comment: @thefourtheye I see the list is now out of sequence, and that is worth thinking about. Order is not important in this case though (it is a list of database ids)

Comment: @ardochhigh Oh then okay :) Then this is the best solution you can get :) If the order matters, check my answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to maintain the order, you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) like this

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain
list1, list2 = [1, 2, 3], [2, 4]
print list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain(list1, list2)))
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If the order of the elements is not important, you can use the `set` like this

```
from itertools import chain
list1, list2 = [1, 2, 3], [2, 4]
print list(set(chain(list1, list2)))
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: `list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain(list1, list2)))` will work both in Python 2.x and Python 3.x.