# Cannot pickle empty ordered_set

Tags: python, pickle

I'm using version 1.2 (currently the latest) of [the ordered_set module](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/ordered-set) linked to from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653974/2829764). I've been getting some weird behavior and have traced it to this:

```
from ordered_set import OrderedSet
import pickle

os_orig = OrderedSet()
print os_orig # 'OrderedSet'
print os_orig.items # '[]'
pickled = pickle.dumps(os_orig)
loaded = pickle.loads(pickled)
print loaded
```

Which raises `AttributeError: 'OrderedSet' object has no attribute 'items'`. Everything goes fine if the OrderedSet is not empty.

Unfortunately I am in over my head here when it comes to pickle--what is going wrong?

EDIT: I should add that the module seems to support pickle. From the README: "added a `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` so it can be pickled"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pickling support for `OrderedSet` breaks when the set is empty, because the state returned by `__getstate__` is essentially empty:

```
>>> OrderedSet().__getstate__()
[]
```

The `pickle` module ends up not calling `__setstate__` when loading the pickle again because `__getstate__`'s return value is empty. Not calling `__setstate__` means the `OrderedSet.__init__()` method never gets called and you have a broken object. See the [`__setstate__` documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__):

> **Note**: For new-style classes, if `__getstate__()` returns a false value, the `__setstate__()` method will not be called.

An empty list is a false value.

The author must've tested only with pickling *non-empty* `OrderedSet()` instances, which works fine.

You can fix the issue by replacing the `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    return (list(self),)
OrderedSet.__getstate__ = __getstate__

def __setstate__(self, state):
    if isinstance(state, tuple):
        state = state[0]
    self.__init__(state)
OrderedSet.__setstate__ = __setstate__
```

Now a non-empty, 1-element tuple is returned, forcing `pickle` to call `__setstate__` even for the empty set. The `__setstate__` will still accept the previous pickle format, a list object.

I've reported this as a [bug with the project](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/ordered-set/issues/5), since closed as resolved.

Comment: `bool(list(),)` (or `bool([],)`) are also a False values.

Comment: @martineau, what are the implications of your comment? I get output from `if (list(),): print "hey"` but not `if bool(list(),): print "hey"`, but I think the former is what counts in this context. Martijn Pieters' code seems to fix the issue for me.

Comment: @martineau: but `bool(([],))` is **not** empty. You do need the parentheses there, without those you are passing in *just* an empty list, not a tuple with one element.

Comment: @kuzzooroo martineau has overlooked the fact that in a call signature you have to have the parentheses around a tuple. `bool([],)` is not passing in a tuple but *just* a single empty list.

Comment: @kuzzooroo: Martijn's correct, my mistake. I got confused due to the lack of the extra set of parentheses. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report -- I've fixed it. I never knew that pickle states had to be truthy objects before this.