# What is the order of elements in a Python set?

Tags: python, set

I do not understand the ordering that Python applies to sets.

For example:

```
visited = set()
visited.add('C')
visited.add('A')
visited.add('B')
print(set)
```

The ordering is `'A', 'C', 'B'`.

Why 'A' is before 'C' (maybe alphabetical order)?

What I have to do in order to preserve the adding ordering, i.e. `'C', 'A', 'B'`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset "A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects."

Comment: possible duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set

Comment: Set is a unordered collection.

Comment: It is unordered but not random tho, I think there are still some restrictions for the ordering, aren't there any ?

Comment: surprised to see this question in 2014.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot have order in sets. and there is no way to tell how Python orders it. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set) answer for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Sets are different than lists. If you want to preserve an order, use a list.
For example :

```
a = []
a.append('C')
a.append('A')
a.append('B')
print a # ['C', 'A', 'B']
```

Comment: But now you can put one element in list twice (which is impossible in sets)