# maintain relative order in a set

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

I am having a list which contains some elements with repetition and from this list I want to generate a list which has no repeated elements in it AND also maintains theie Order in the List.

I tried `set(['1','1','2','3','4','4','5','2','2','3','3','6'])` and got the output as `set(['1', '3', '2', '5', '4', '6'])`

But I want the output as *set(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'])* i.e. maintain the relative order of the elements already present.

How to do this??? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Sets are explicitly *not ordered*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
In [9]: x = ['1','1','2','3','4','4','5','2','2','3','3','6']

In [10]: s = set()

In [11]: y = []

In [12]: for i in x:
    ...:     if i not in s:
    ...:         y.append(i)
    ...:         s.add(i)
    ...:         

In [13]: y
Out[13]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

As noted by Martijn, a set is unordered by definition, so you need a list to store the result. See also [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1653970/2647279).