# Create sets from list in order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a set from a list which I need it to be in order.

```
someList = ['from', 'from', 'who', 'are', 'are', 'frost', 'fire', 'are']

someSet = set(list)
```

Doing that yields a random ordered sets.

I need it to always be in order like

```
someSet >> {'from', 'who', 'are', 'frost', 'fire', 'are'}
```

Comment: Sets are *unordered*. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get the first x element of a list, which can not be a repeat. So order is important here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set

Comment: Then a `set` (on its own, at least) is not the right data structure for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
someist = ['from', 'from', 'who', 'are', 'are', 'frost', 'fire', 'are']
new_list[]
for x in somelist:
    if x not in new_list:
        new_list.append(x)
```

In the above code, if new_list will have the element it will not append, so you will get in order

Comment: Membership testing in a list is `O(n)`; you should still be using a `set` to keep track of the items already seen.