# Remove duplicates from list python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a program that removes duplicates from a list, but my program keeps throwing the error "list index out of range" on line 5, `if n/(sequence[k]) == 1:`. I can't figure this out. Am I right in thinking that the possible values of "k" are 0, 1, and 2? How is "sequence" with any of those as the index outside of the possible index range?

```
def remove_duplicates(sequence):
    new_list = sequence
    for n in sequence:
        for k in range(len(sequence)):
            if n/(sequence[k]) == 1:
                new_list.remove(sequence[k])
    print new_list

remove_duplicates([1,2,3])
```

Comment: Why not just `list(set(your_list))`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/python-removing-duplicates-in-lists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly suggest Akavall's answer:

```
list(set(your_list))
```

As to why you get out of range errors: Python passes by reference, that is sequence and new_list still point at the same memory location. Changing new_list also changes sequence.

And finally, you are comparing items with themselves, and then remove them. So basically even if you used a copy of sequence, like:

```
new_list = list(sequence)
```

or

```
new_list = sequence[:]
```

It would return an empty list.

Comment: This does not guarantee the same order of the remaining elements.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is concurrent modification of the list:

```
for k in range(len(sequence)):
    if n/(sequence[k]) == 1:
        new_list.remove(sequence[k])
```

It may seem removing from new_list shouldn't effect sequence, but you did `new_list = sequence` at the beginning of the function. This means new_list actually literally is sequence, perhaps what you meant is `new_list=list(sequence)`, to copy the list?

If you accept that they are the same list, the error is obvious. When you remove items, the length, and the indexes change.

P.S. As mentioned in a comment by @Akavall, all you need is:

```
sequence=list(set(sequence))
```

To make sequence contain no dupes. Another option, if you need to preserve ordering, is:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
sequence=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(sequence))
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. But I still don't understand. Aren't I modifying 'new_list', not 'sequence'?

Comment: @Crytera sorry, that was just for example, I've fixed it now if you wanna accept the answer.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but I wanted more to know exactly why the error was thrown if I'm not modifying 'sequence'.

Comment: @Crytera explained your problem

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like `list(set(your_list))` because it's not guaranteed to preserved order, you could grab [the OrderedSet recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653974/2829764) and then do:

```
from ordered_set import OrderedSet

foo = list("face a dead cabbage")
print foo
print list(set(foo)) # Order might change
print list(OrderedSet(foo)) # Order preserved
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# like @Akavall suggested
def remove_duplicates(sequence):
    # returns unsorted unique list
    return list(set(sequence))

# create a list, if ele from input not in that list, append.
def remove_duplicates(sequence):
    lst = []
    for i in sequence:
        if i not in lst:
            lst.append(i)
    # returns unsorted unique list
    return lst
```