# How do I remove duplicate words from a list in python without using sets?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have the following python code which almost works for me (I'm SO close!).  I have text file from one Shakespeare's plays that I'm opening: 
Original text file:

"But soft what light through yonder window breaks

It is the east and Juliet is the sun

Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon

Who is already sick and pale with grief"

And the result of the code I worte gives me is this:

['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'and', 'and',
 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'is', 'is', 'kill',
 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'sun', 'the', 'the', 'the',
 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']

So this is almost what I want:  It's already in a list sorted the way I want it, but how do I remove the duplicate words?  I'm trying to create a new ResultsList and append the words to it, but it gives me the above result without getting rid of the duplicate words.  If I "print ResultsList" it just dumps a ton of words out.  They way I have it now is close, but I want to get rid of the extra "and's", "is's", "sun's" and "the's".... I want to keep it simple and use append(), but I'm not sure how I can get it to work. I don't want to do anything crazy with the code.   What simple thing am I missing from my code inorder to remove the duplicate words?

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")  
fhand = open(fname)
NewList = list()      #create new list
ResultList = list()    #create new results list I want to append words to

for line in fhand:
    line.rstrip()       #strip white space
    words = line.split()    #split lines of words and make list
        NewList.extend(words)   #make the list from 4 lists to 1 list

    for word in line.split():   #for each word in line.split()
        if words not in line.split():    #if a word isn't in line.split
            NewList.sort()             #sort it
            ResultList.append(words)   #append it, but this doesn't work.


print NewList
#print ResultList (doesn't work the way I want it to)
```

Comment: Would it be OK to use dictionaries?

Comment: Why not use `OrderedSet` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did have a couple logic error with your code. I fixed them, hope it helps.

```
fname = "stuff.txt"
fhand = open(fname)
AllWords = list()      #create new list
ResultList = list()    #create new results list I want to append words to

for line in fhand:
    line.rstrip()   #strip white space
    words = line.split()    #split lines of words and make list
    AllWords.extend(words)   #make the list from 4 lists to 1 list

AllWords.sort()  #sort list

for word in AllWords:   #for each word in line.split()
    if word not in ResultList:    #if a word isn't in line.split            
        ResultList.append(word)   #append it.


print(ResultList)
```

Tested on Python 3.4, no importing.

Comment: Thank you!  That is what I was looking for.  I wanted to keep it "simple", I see what I did wrong now.  Once again, thank you kindly, much appreciated.

Comment: If the same word but in a different case appeared in the file, this would report duplicate words. e.g. if 'is' and 'Is' appear in the file, you would get 'is' and 'Is' in the final list. As there are no cases of this in your sample data I suppose its not too much of an issue.

Answer (score 8):

```
mylist = ['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'is', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'sun', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
newlist = sorted(set(mylist), key=lambda x:mylist.index(x))
print(newlist)
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

`newlist` contains a list of the set of unique values from `mylist`, sorted by each item's index in `mylist`.

Comment: Thank you.  I was wondering if I could do this without using a set.  Keeping with the list theme....?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid sets? They're ideal for unique membership.

Comment: That's what I get for trying to save a few keystrokes here and there while testing. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: I am not looking to avoid sets for ever.  I'm just new to python and wanted to progress in such away where I understand the basics, then move to more advanced stuff.  But I appreciate your code.  I can implement that in the future.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Below function might help.

```
   def remove_duplicate_from_list(temp_list):
        if temp_list:
            my_list_temp = []
            for word in temp_list:
                if word not in my_list_temp:
                    my_list_temp.append(word)
            return my_list_temp
        else: return []
```

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative to using a `set` would be to use a dictionary. The [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#module-collections) module contains a class called [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) which is specialized dictionary for counting the number of times each of its keys are seen. Using it you could do something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

wordlist = ['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'and',
            'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'is',
            'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'sun',
            'the', 'the', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']

newlist = sorted(Counter(wordlist), 
                 key=lambda w: w.lower())  # case insensitive sort
print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
['already', 'and', 'Arise', 'breaks', 'But', 'east', 'envious', 'fair',
 'grief', 'is', 'It', 'Juliet', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick',
 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'Who', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

Comment: Much obliged. I didn't know about counter.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, it walks the list and adds elements to a new list if they are not the same as the last element added to the new list.

```
def unique(lst):
    """ Assumes lst is already sorted """
    unique_list = []
    for el in lst:
        if el != unique_list[-1]:
            unique_list.append(el)
    return unique_list
```

You could also use collections.groupby which works similarly

```
from collections import groupby

# lst must already be sorted 
unique_list = [key for key, _ in groupby(lst)]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's something I could use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use plain old lists. Almost certainly not as efficient as `Counter`.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")  

Words = []
with open(fname) as fhand:
    for line in fhand:
        line = line.strip()
        # lines probably not needed
        #if line.startswith('"'):
        #    line = line[1:]
        #if line.endswith('"'):
        #    line = line[:-1]
        Words.extend(line.split())

UniqueWords = []
for word in Words:
    if word.lower() not in UniqueWords:
        UniqueWords.append(word.lower())

print Words
UniqueWords.sort()
print UniqueWords
```

This always checks against the lowercase version of the word, to ensure the same word but in a different case configuration is not counted as 2 different words.

I added checks to remove the double quotes at the start and end of the file, but if they are not present in the actual file. These lines could be disregarded.

Comment: Thank you, that is an even better way to alphabatize.

Comment: you could also check / remove the quotes with `line = line.strip().strip('"')`

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code.
I think you mean:

```
for word in line.split():   #for each word in line.split()
    if words not in ResultList:    #if a word isn't in ResultList
```

Comment: Thank you, I mixed that up.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in lst:
            lst.append(word)
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```