# Convert 4 sentences from text file and append all the words into a new list without repeating the words

Tags: python

I have been working on program to read 4 sentences from .txt file and append all the words into a new empty list.

My code is as follow:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split()
    words.sort()
    if words not in lst:
      lst.append(words)
      print lst
```

And i got the following results:

> [['But', 'breaks', 'light', 'soft', 'through', 'what', 'window',
>   'yonder']] [['But', 'breaks', 'light', 'soft', 'through', 'what',
>   'window', 'yonder'], ['It', 'Juliet', 'and', 'east', 'is', 'is',
>   'sun', 'the', 'the']] [['But', 'breaks', 'light', 'soft', 'through',
>   'what', 'window', 'yonder'], ['It', 'Juliet', 'and', 'east', 'is',
>   'is', 'sun', 'the', 'the'], ['Arise', 'and', 'envious', 'fair',
>   'kill', 'moon', 'sun', 'the']] [['But', 'breaks', 'light', 'soft',
>   'through', 'what', 'window', 'yonder'], ['It', 'Juliet', 'and',
>   'east', 'is', 'is', 'sun', 'the', 'the'], ['Arise', 'and', 'envious',
>   'fair', 'kill', 'moon', 'sun', 'the'], ['Who', 'already', 'and',
>   'grief', 'is', 'pale', 'sick', 'with']]

What could i do to obtain the following:

> ['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks',
>   'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon',
>   'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window',
>   'with', 'yonder']

The sentences are:
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief

Comment: can you show those 4 sentences content?

Comment: Can you explain in words the problem with the output?  That might help you see what is wrong with the algorithm.

Comment: Look at the difference between list.append and list.extend.  Also if you are looking for unique things then you want the set object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting each line into a list of words correctly using `line.split()`, but you are not iterating through the new list named `words` that you just created. You are instead comparing the list `words` as an object to the contents of `lst`, and then appending `words` as an object to `lst`. This causes `lst` to be a list of lists, as you've shown in the results you've been receiving.

In order to achieve the array of words you're looking for, you'll have to iteratw through `words` and add each word individually as long as it is not in `lst`:

```
for word in words:
    if word not in lst:
      lst.append(word)
```

edit: Found [another question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29312508/7032806) regarding the same problem - Probably for the same class assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a set that will uniquely list elements :

```
my_string = "But soft what light through yonder window breaks It is the east and Juliet is the sun Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon Who is already sick and pale with grief"    
lst = set(my_string.split(' '))
```

This will give you what you want. You can use `set`on strings, lists etc. [sets in python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a set, and to append each word.

```
file_name = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
with open(file_name, 'r') as fh: 
    all_words = set()
    for line in fh:
        line = line.rstrip()
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:     
            all_words.add(word)
print(all_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

A [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) can be used to remove duplicates, and the [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method will split on any kind of whitespace - including line-endings. So this task can be reduced to a quite simple one-liner:

```
lst = sorted(set(open(fname).read().split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same assignment. The code I have used is as follows:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in lst:
            lst.append(word)
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```