# How to convert list of list to list of frozenset in original order in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of lists and I want to convert to list of frozenset in original order. I've tried the code below but the output isn't in the original order.

```
data=[[118, 175, 181, 348, 353], [117, 175, 181, 371, 282, 297], [119, 166, 176, 54, 349]]
```

my code:

```
>>> transactionList=list()
>>> for rec in data:
      transaction = frozenset(rec)
      transactionList.append(transaction)
```

output i got is not in original order:

```
>>> transactionList
    [frozenset([353, 348, 181, 118, 175]), frozenset([297, 175, 371, 181, 282, 117]), frozenset([176, 349, 54, 166, 119])]
```

my expected output in original order:

```
>>> transactionList
    [frozenset([118, 175, 181, 348, 353]), frozenset([117, 175, 181, 371, 282, 297]),frozenset([119, 166, 176, 54, 349])]
```

Comment: what is a frozen list?

Comment: Sorry, frozenset i means... I will edit the question

Comment: I there any particular reason you need a `frozenset`? Would a list of tuples, after removing the duplicates but keeping the order, do the job? Tuples are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

`frozenset`s, like `set`s, have no defined order. See [Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set) for ways to overcome this with custom classes.