# how to intersect a list and set in python and preserve the order of the list?

Tags: python, list, set

How can I intersect a list and a set to preserve the order of the list?
Simple example:

```
k=[1,2,3,4]
d={3,2}
d.intersection(k)
[2,3]#this is the ideal result
```

edit: speed is the most important factor here

Comment: Are the elements of `k` unique?

Comment: no, but they are in ascending order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to use a list comprehension, which lets you keep the order by filtering:

```
[i for i in k if i in d]
```

Demo:

```
>>> k = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> d = {2, 3}
>>> [i for i in k if i in d]
[2, 3]
```

For Python 3, this is the fastest option available; you could use `list(filter(d.__contains__, l))` but this is slower on this trivially small example:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> def listcomp(k, d):
...     return [i for i in k if i in d]
...
>>> def filtered(k, d):
...     return list(filter(d.__contains__, k))
...
>>> timeit('listcomp(k, d)', 'from __main__ import listcomp, k, d')
0.49590064199946937
>>> timeit('filtered(k, d)', 'from __main__ import filtered, k, d')
0.6533352420010488
```

and timings worsen when the data sets grow in size:

```
>>> import random
>>> k = sorted([random.randrange(1000) for _ in range(1000)])
>>> d = {random.randrange(1000) for _ in range(100)}
>>> timeit('listcomp(k, d)', 'from __main__ import listcomp, k, d', number=10000)
0.30027976899873465
>>> timeit('filtered(k, d)', 'from __main__ import filtered, k, d', number=10000)
0.4524774450001132
```

In Python 2, `filter()` is the faster option, given large enough inputs:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> import random
>>> def listcomp(k, d):
...     return [i for i in k if i in d]
...
>>> def filtered(k, d):
...     return filter(d.__contains__, k)
...
>>> k = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> d = {2, 3}
>>> timeit('listcomp(k, d)', 'from __main__ import listcomp, k, d')
0.4015800952911377
>>> timeit('filtered(k, d)', 'from __main__ import filtered, k, d')
0.4407978057861328
>>> k = sorted([random.randrange(1000) for _ in range(1000)])
>>> d = {random.randrange(1000) for _ in range(100)}
>>> timeit('listcomp(k, d)', 'from __main__ import listcomp, k, d', number=10000)
0.4594550132751465
>>> timeit('filtered(k, d)', 'from __main__ import filtered, k, d', number=10000)
0.28088998794555664
```

I'm not aware of any faster options; the [available ordered set implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set) are all Pure-python solutions, and slower still.

Comment: This was my original solution, but it's too slow.

Comment: @user4757074: it would have been helpful if you mentioned this in your question.

Comment: @user4757074: there are no other standard-library options that I know of. There are ordered-set implementations on PyPI but these are pure-Python implementations and likely slower still.

Comment: I don't think you can do better than one 'in' comparison for each item in the list-

Comment: i don’t think the ascending order of the list is very helpful here in terms of performance

Comment: @taylorswift: the order doesn't make any difference; I only added the `sorted()` call to match the OP data set.

Comment: i was speaking to the OP when he/she says that this answer is too slow. I don’t think you can get much better than this in pure python