# finding all elements in list are same or not?

Tags: python, list

finding whether all elements in the list are same or not based on the following scenario:-

I am getting price value at every 5 min interval.for first 20 min. I have to simply store these value somewhere for further comparison. I am creating list for that purpose:

```
initPrice=[]    // create empty list
```

after that, I am appending values  to list by using:

```
initPrice.append(someValue)
```

so till 20 min, means 4 values will be appended to list. like:-

```
initPrice=[20,23,20,40]
```

Now I have to check whether all elements in the list are same or not. so I did-

```
if(len(set(initprice))<2):
    print("TRUE")
else:
     print("FALSE")
```

but the scenario is like live streaming data, so after every 20 min, I want to do the same task again and again on the list, without increasing the length size. its more look like queue first in first out,so after every 20 min, I am doing the same task on updated value. the only problem with list.append is it will increase the list size, that i dont want.

it's like after every 5 min new value should store at one end and older value should remove from another end, that's why i said its more look like FIFO mechanisms

Comment: This questions is relatively poorly worded.  Are you trying to limit the size of the list to 4, and then empty the list after 20 minutes?

Comment: If `initPrice` is used only to keep track of prices. Why not create it as `set` instead of `list` at the first place? And yes, set is the right choice for this

Comment: @Tyler nope, it's like after every 5 min new value should store at one end and older value should remove from another end, that's why i said its more look like FIFO mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Python `deque` initialized with the `maxlen` parameter:

```
In [2]: from collections import deque

In [3]: queue = deque(maxlen=4)

In [4]: queue.append(4)

In [5]: queue.append(6)

In [6]: queue.append(5)

In [7]: queue.append(3)

In [8]: queue
Out[8]: deque([4, 6, 5, 3])

In [9]: queue.append(88)

In [10]: queue
Out[10]: deque([6, 5, 3, 88])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the list only if the value does not exist:

```
if someValue not in initPrice:
    initPrice.append(someValue)
```

And use `initPrice.pop()` to remove to first value appended to the list.

If you do not need an order, consider using a set instead.  See also: [Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)

Answer (score 0):

Python has a Queue class which you could use.  Basically you would want to place into the queue whenever you got a new value, but if you ever had 4 or more values, remove a value first.  It may look something like this.
`

```
if len(initPrice) >= 4:
  initPrice.get()

initPrice.put(someValue)
```

You would init the queue like this:

```
initPrice = Queue()
```

Comment: Queue is a complex data structure used for synchronizing (threads etc.). A simple list should be enough for this problem.

Comment: @Udi but the beauty of python is blackboxing everything and not worrying about things right haha?  That's a good point though.  Would definitely make sense to whip up a simpler implementation of a queue and utilize that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use modulus to reuse the same 4 spots

```
prices = [0, 0, 0, 0]
i = 0
while True:
    prices[i%4] = getNewPrice()
    i += 1
    # every 20 minutes
    if (i % 4 == 0):
        # check all same and print
    # sleep 5 minutes
```

Answer (score -1):

Python lists are naturally made to be a stack - they support the `pop` function.  So if you wanted a **stack**, it would be simple:

```
>>>initPrice = []
>>>initPrice.append(1)
>>>initPrice.append(2)

>>>initPrice.pop()
2
>>>initPrice
[1]
```

However, if you want **queue** functionality, you can still use lists.  <strike>You just need to slice them.</strike>  As juanpa.arrivillaga and Udi were quick to point out, you can pop from the front by passing an index of 0 to the `pop` function:

```
>>>initPrice = []
>>>initPrice.append(1)
>>>initPrice.append(2)

>>>initPrice.pop(0)
1
>>>initPrice
[2]
```

Comment: to pop from the front it is better to just simply `init_price.pop(0)`. Of course, the performance of such an operation is linear, but that might not matter with such a small structure.

Comment: huh.  And that's why I like posting on SO.  I get to learn things by attempting to teach.  I didn't expect pop to take an argument, so never checked.

Comment: A tip to people coming to Python from other languages: if you wish it could be so it probably is!

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/353/  :-)  (And try `import antigravity` in a python shell...)