# How to remove duplicates from a list of lists, having different orders

Tags: arrays, algorithm, python-3.x

This time I am working on Combination sum problem Leetcode. This is very interesting problem which goes like this.

Given a set of candidate numbers (C) (without duplicates) and a target number (T), find all unique combinations in C where the candidate numbers sums to T.

The same repeated number may be chosen from C unlimited number of times.

Note:

1. All numbers (including target) will be positive integers.
2. The solution set must not contain duplicate combinations.

Source: [Leetcode: Combination sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/?tab=Description)

For example, given candidate set `[2, 3, 6, 7]` and target `7`,
A solution set is:

`[[7],[2, 2, 3]]`

Now, I have written the following algorithm which solves my purposes, almost. The problem is my algorithm doesn't remove the duplicates. Let me show you how:

```
 def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):
        """
        :type candidates: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        candies = []
        if target in candidates and len(candidates) ==1:
            return [[target]]
        for idx in range(len(candidates)):
            residual = target
            count =0
            while residual >= candidates[idx]:
                residual -= candidates[idx]
                if candidates[idx] == target:
                    candies.append([candidates[idx]])
                count += 1
                if (residual in candidates and (residual-candidates[idx]) <= candidates[idx]):
                    candies.append([candidates[idx]]*count+[residual])
        return candies
```

So we have a result list known as `candies` (short for candidates, super bad variable name but I was not dealing with the problem seriously, previously).

Steps:

1. The first `if` statement checks the base case if we have only one candidate and returns that as a list of list.
2. We iterate through the `candidates`, on each iteration we initialize the `residual` to target and `count` to zero. `count` help us track of how many times we repetitively call the same number and then create a list of lists at the end. `[candidates[idx]]*count+[residual]`.
3. The final inner loop is a `while` loop which iterates until our residual is greater than or equal to the `candidate[idx]`. Thus taking each element from the `candidates` one at a time and check if the repetitively selecting the same element sums to target. Also, the 'if' statement adds any intermediate elements that are in the list and can become `candies` (result set).

Thus solving the problem partially. My problem is we get same combinations of elements. Here's how:
`input: [2,3,6,7,1]` target = `3`
we select `2` we repetitively select it until our `residual` (`7`) is below the `2`, we choose 2 one time and then search and then choose `1`. Giving us `[2,1]` but when it goes to `1` checks. and then choose `2` giving us `[1,2]` which is a duplicate combination. How can solve this problem? Any improvement that you may see?

Comment: sets my friend -- use sets

Comment: @dawg Yes, yes I know the work around but what if we have such situation? (sets are much much efficient in python, I agree.) Can we find any other check before appending?

Comment: See this post about ordered sets in Python and consider implementing a simple membership test before appending new results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set

Answer (score 0):

Sort your successful subsets. Then, before appending a successful subset, check to see if it exists in your collection of successful candidate combinations.

```
# suppose your target = 3
old_combinations = [[1,2]]
new_combination = [2, 1]

if sorted(new_combination) not in old_combinations:
    old_combinations.append(sorted(new_combination))
    print("found a unique combo!")
else:
    pass
```