# sort set into list in python in order it was first appended

Tags: python, list, sorting, set, append

I want to loop through my set in an order. I know sets are unordered and will have to sort it into a list and have done so by sorting the set numerically, but I now want to try to sort it in the order the numbers were first appended to the set. Is this possible to do after the set has been created or will this require me to the numbers to populate something other than a set? The order will need to keep the order the numbers were first appended to the set

Comment: No, it's not possible unless you augment the items you're adding to the set with extra information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)

Comment: Are you required to use a set and not a list?

Comment: Not entirely necessary to use a set in the first place, could probably get around it by using a list but only populating if unique. Not quite a duplicate of that question, but I could potentially use a similar solution. How might I potentially add extra information to the set e.g. give each item a rank or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way, short of augmenting the elements inserted with some sort of ordering, is probably to use the keys of an `ordereddict` to store & retreive the elements of your set, with dummy values mapped to these keys.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
seq = [6, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 0]
my_set = OrderedDict()
for elt in seq:
    my_set[elt] = True
```

You can now iterate or retrieve the keys in the order you inserted them. You get the same properties as a set, i/e uniqueness, fast insertion, retrieval, and contains; what you don't get are specific set operations like symmetric difference, etc...

Comment: It might be a better idea to pick a truthy value for `my_set[elt]`.

Comment: Maybe, we know little of the use case. Why do you think so?

Comment: I think this would work well. I specifically needed the uniqueness of the set. I don't see why a value for the dictionary would be necessary? I think just using the keys would be fine.

Comment: `my_set[elt]=True` would make a clear distinction between objects that are a key in the dict and those that arent. With `my_set[elt]=None`, `my_set.get()` would return `None` for every object.

Comment: Yes, thank you @EricDuminil, that makes sense. I will amend my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, a set is not ordered. There is no way of finding out in which order the elements were appended to the set.
However, you could use a list for that. Every time you add an element to the set append it to the list as well and then you know the order.
But beware: a set only contains each same element once whereas a list can contain the same element multiple times. I am not sure how this effects your use of this feature.
You could work around it by only appending to the list if the element is not yet in the list.

```
s = set()
l = []

elem = 1
if elem not in l:
    l.append(elem)
s.add(elem)

print(s)
print(l)
```

Comment: You could also create a list and convert it to a set when necessary using `set(l)`

Comment: But if I was to convert to a set I then lose the ordering once again if I am to loop through the set afterwards. I don't think I can use a set here at all if the order of appending items is lost, so I think a unique list will do the job

Comment: Yes, list definitely seems the most appropriate. We were just suggesting the conversion to a set if it was necessary. (E.g. you could convert to a set to make use of its specific functionality without getting rid of the original list)