# Why does this return statement return a list instead of a set in?

Tags: python, list, set, return

It's been a little while. I've currently picked up Python and I ran accross something paculiar and I don't understand why, I'm new to Python and I'm learning it through a book but it might be a little outdated. However I like books over video sometimes. Anyway this is the issue

```
def search_vowels(word):
vowels = set('aeeeiouuu')
return sorted(vowels.intersection(set(word)))
```

With this piece of code, it  basically has two sets and one called vowels and the other is whatever gets passed to the function "search_vowels()"

However the interesting happens when I return the object it creates a new LIST rather than a SET. I use the intersection function to find the common string values in vowels from word and instead of returning a set, it returns list? can someone explain?

I know I can set the current returned list to a set by declaring one

```
common = sorted(vowels.intersection(set(word)))
return set(common)
```

BUT why does it not initially return a set? Is there something I'm not aware off? Please forgive my ignorance and thank you for any expertise given. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think sorted returns a list. :)
However, "sort" just sorts the item in place

Comment: Please check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) before posting.

Comment: FWIW, sets are "generally unordered" (this is true of the standard Python set); and the `sorted` function (which is also generic across all *sequences*) returns an ordered *list* - to get an ordered set one generally has to pick a [*specific implementation*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set), and this would have to applied post-sorting as `sorted` would still return a *list* (or used in a manner in which the "ordered set's logic" applied).

Comment: Wow I should've checked the docs, I should create this habit. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

`sorted` always returns a list. it takes in any type of iterable and returns a list of the sorted values. Here is the prompt you get in python IDLE when using `sorted`:

```
sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list
```

Comment: Wow, I should've checked the docs, that literally the first line, thank you for showing me this @sam-pyt I understand now.

Comment: @sam-pyt do you understand how electrons flow through a semiconductor? ;)