# Subtracting list along with duplicates in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists:

```
l1=['TUDCAPL.CLM_NUM_CD',
    'TUDCAPL.CRT_TS',
    'TUDCAPL.CLM_NUM_CD',
    'TUDCAPL.CRT_TS',
    'TUDCAPJ.CLM_NUM_CD',
    'TUDCAPJ.CRT_TS']

l2 = ['TUDCAPL.CLM_NUM_CD',
      'TUDCAPL.CRT_TS']
```

I want my result to be

```
l3 = ['TUDCAPL.CLM_NUM_CD',
      'TUDCAPL.CRT_TS',
      'TUDCAPJ.CLM_NUM_CD',
      'TUDCAPJ.CRT_TS']
```

I used `l3 = [x for x in l1 if x not in l2]`
but the result is `['TUDCAPJ.CLM_NUM_CD','TUDCAPJ.CRT_TS']` *ignoring the duplicates*. How can I get the duplicates along with other unique values?

Comment: Will there are situations when `l2` contains something that is not in `l1`?

Comment: Should both lists `l1` and `l2` remain intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the list (if you do not want to change `l1`). Loop *once* over the items in `l2` and remove it from the new list. The `remove` function will discard the first occurrence of each item, leaving the others and the order unaffected.

```
l1 = ['TUDCAPL.CLM_NUM_CD',
      'TUDCAPL.CRT_TS',
      'TUDCAPL.CLM_NUM_CD',
      'TUDCAPL.CRT_TS',
      'TUDCAPJ.CLM_NUM_CD',
      'TUDCAPJ.CRT_TS']

l2 = ['TUDCAPL.CLM_NUM_CD',
      'TUDCAPL.CRT_TS']

l3 = list(l1)
for x in l2:
    if x in l3:
        l3.remove(x)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(l3)
```

Result:

```
['TUDCAPL.CLM_NUM_CD', 
 'TUDCAPL.CRT_TS', 
 'TUDCAPJ.CLM_NUM_CD', 
 'TUDCAPJ.CRT_TS']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
l3 = set(l1)
l3.update(l2)
print l3
```

Comment: order isnt maintained :-(

Comment: Look for OrderedSet

Comment: this might help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set

Comment: What if the number of duplicates is more than 2. Say l1= [2, 2, 2] and l2 =[2].

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the best solution but it will keep the order and the unique elements of your list:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l1=['TUDCAPL.CLM_NUM_CD',
    'TUDCAPL.CRT_TS',
    'TUDCAPL.CLM_NUM_CD',
    'TUDCAPL.CRT_TS',
    'TUDCAPJ.CLM_NUM_CD',
    'TUDCAPJ.CRT_TS']

l2 = ['TUDCAPL.CLM_NUM_CD',
      'TUDCAPL.CRT_TS']


d = OrderedDict(zip(l1,[None]*len(l1)))
d2 = OrderedDict(zip(l2,[None]*len(l2)))

d.update(d2)
print(d.keys()) # this will contain the resulting list of strings
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to copy your list to a set (this way you get unique values):

```
l1 = ['TUDCAPL.CLM_NUM_CD', 
      'TUDCAPL.CRT_TS',
      'TUDCAPL.CLM_NUM_CD', 
      'TUDCAPL.CRT_TS', 
      'TUDCAPJ.CLM_NUM_CD', 
      'TUDCAPJ.CRT_TS']
s1 = set(l1)
print(s1)
```

Comment: This removes the duplicates. They should be preserved.

Comment: why you want to preserve the duplicate values if want go for dictionary and maintain there count in value

Comment: It's the OP's requirement, not mine.