# How to add a value in a specific location/index in set in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, set

How do i add a set of values in order (per inventory) from a user's input for e.g. `{fruit:{1,2,3,4},{veggies:{5,6,7,8}}`

Nothing i've tried so far ever worked.

Here's my code:

```
def Create_Inventory():

    clear()
    inventory_dictionary = {}

    count_inventory = int(input("Enter the number of Inventories: "))

    for num_inv in range(count_inventory):

        add_inventory = str(input("Enter Inventory #%d: " % (num_inv + 1)))
        inventory_dictionary[add_inventory] = set()

    for find_key in inventory_dictionary:
        count_item = int(input("\nHow many items in %s inventory: " % find_key))
        for num_item in range(count_item):
            #add_item = input("Enter item #%d: " % (num_item + 1))
            #inventory_dictionary[find_key].add(add_item)
            add_item = set(input("Enter item #%d: " % (num_item + 1)))
            inventory_dictionary[find_key].update(add_item)
```

My full code:
https://pastebin.com/gu5DJX5K

Answer (score 2):

[Sets are unordered collections.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) What you want is impossible. Consider these alternatives:

- `list`, ordered but permits duplicates.
- `dict.keys` in Python 3.6+, where dictionaries are insertion ordered.
- `OrderedDict.keys` in Python versions prior to 3.6.
- Create a custom class, e.g. [this recipe](https://github.com/ActiveState/code/blob/3b27230f418b714bc9a0f897cb8ea189c3515e99/recipes/Python/576696_OrderedSet_with_Weakrefs/README.md).
- Use a 3rd party library, e.g. [`ordered-set`](https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/).

See also: [Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)

Comment: I see. That's why. I'll check on those thank you. Have a wonderful day sir!