# Sort sets of objects by numbers in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a sequence of lists such as :

```
>>> result


  [['Human_COII_1000-4566_hsp', 'Human_COII_500-789_hsp', 'Human_COII_100-300_hsp'], ['Human_COI_100-300_hsp', 'Human_COI_500-789_hsp', 'Human_COI_1000-4566_hsp']]
```

and I would like with each list to sort them by the `number-number` and get:

```
[['Human_COII_100-300_hsp', 'Human_COII_500-789_hsp', 'Human_COII_1000-4566_hsp'], ['Human_COI_100-300_hsp', 'Human_COI_500-789_hsp', 'Human_COI_1000-4566_hsp']]
```

I tried:

```
for i in result:
    sorted(i)
```

but the order is not the one I wanted.

Comment: What are we sorting? There's a list of sets. The sets have items. Are we sorting the order of the sets, or do we want to make a list of all set elements and sort that?

Comment: I want to sort the items within each sets.

Comment: Sets do not have order. You can sort them, but when you make new sets of that, they won't be sorted. Although you can display them in order.

Comment: This looks like what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set/1653974

Comment: So how could I display the items 3 inside these 2 sets in order?

Comment: Maybe I can change into a list of list such as. [['Human_COII_1000-4566_hsp', 'Human_COII_500-789_hsp', 'Human_COII_100-300_hsp'], {'Human_COI_500-789_hsp', 'Human_COI_100-300_hsp', 'Human_COI_1000-4566_hsp']] ?

Comment: I changed the post with a list of list in order to be cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a new sorted `list` using comprehension,

```
>>> import re
>>> x
[set(['Human_COII_1000-4566_hsp', 'Human_COII_100-300_hsp', 'Human_COII_500-789_hsp']), set(['Human_COI_100-300_hsp', 'Human_COI_500-789_hsp', 'Human_COI_1000-4566_hsp'])]
>>>
>>> # for python2
>>> [sorted(y, key=lambda item: map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', item))) for y in x]
[['Human_COII_100-300_hsp', 'Human_COII_500-789_hsp', 'Human_COII_1000-4566_hsp'], ['Human_COI_100-300_hsp', 'Human_COI_500-789_hsp', 'Human_COI_1000-4566_hsp']]
>>>
>>> # python3
>>> [sorted(y, key=lambda item: tuple(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', item)))) for y in x]
```