# Ordering a set in base python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Is there a way of ordering a set in base python?

For example:

```
A = {1, 2, 3}
B = {3, -6, 2, 0}
print union(A, B)
```

Expected Output:

```
({-6, 0, 1, 2, 3}, 5)
```

My attempt:

```
x = A | B
y = len(x)
print((set(x), y))
```

My output:

```
({0, 1, 2, 3, -6}, 5)
```

I have read some of the answers for other questions and there are ways of doing it with various packages, but for this exercise, I am NOT meant to import any packages, just doing it in base python (if that is what it is called) if possible.

Comment: `set`s are inherently not ordered data structure, you may use a sorted list

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set

Answer (score 1):

No, sets are unordered by definition and implementation. To create a sorted list, convert your set to a list and sort it:

```
List = sorted(your_set)
```

Comment: Sort of works, but when it is converted back to a set, it is unsorted again.

Comment: @william3031, sets are __unordered__. There's _no way_ to sort a set.

Comment: No worries. Thanks. I am just wondering how to get to the expected output.