# fast list subtraction for big list with o(n) order in python

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I have two big string list in python. I want to subtract these two list fast with the order of o(n). I found some way like remove second list elements in a loop from first list, or converting list to set() (problem:change order of list)and use minus(-) operator, but these methods are not efficient. Is there any way for doing this operation?

```
a=['1','2','3',...,'500000']
b=['1','2','3',...,'200000']

c=a-b

c=['200001','200002',...,'500000']
```

Comment: isnt the set solution still O(n)?

Comment: @roganjosh yes,I canuse numpy, but I dont know how to use it for subtrating two 1D list

Comment: I took the numerical values too literally and went off-course. sets are the way to go, not numpy.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh, if we have big sets, subtracting is o(n), but converting big list to set is slow

Comment: its just about the best solution you can have for this kind of subtraction. And conversion is O(n) too, so its tough to expect anything better.

Comment: `a = list(range(1000000)); %timeit set(a)` --> `59.3 ms ± 449 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem, as formulated, is:

- Go through A
- For each element, search it in B and take it if it's not found
- No assumptions about elements is made

For arbitrary data, list search is O(N), set search is O(1), converting to set is O(N). Going through A is O(N).

So it's O(N^2) with only lists and O(N) if converting B to a set.

The only way you can speed it up is to make either iterating or searching more efficient -- which is impossible without using some additional knowledge about your data. E.g.

- In your example, your data are sequential numbers, so you can take `A[len(B):]`.
- If you are going to use the same B multiple times, you can cache the set
- You can make B a set right off the bat (if order needs to be preserved, you can use [an ordered set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set))
- If all data are of the same type and are short, [you can use `numpy` arrays](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modify-numpy-array-to-store-an-arbitrary-length-string/) and its fast [`setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html#numpy.setdiff1d)
- etc

Comment: set() change the order of list, if I want to reorder to main order o(n^2) operation needed.