# Delete duplicates from list but consider the type of elements and preserve order

Tags: python, list, types

Task:

Develop a `clean_list (list_to_clean)` function,
which takes 1 argument - a list of any values ​​(strings, integers, and floats) of any length,
and returns a list that has the same values ​​but does not have duplicate items. This means that if there is a value in the original list in several instances, the first "instance" of the value remains in place, and the second, third, and so on are deleted.

Example:

Function call: `clean_list ([32, 32.1, 32.0, -32, 32, '32'])`
Returns: `[32, 32.1, 32.0, -32, '32']`

My code:

```
def clean_list(list_to_clean):
   no_dubl_lst = [value for _, value in set((type(x), x) for x in list_to_clean)]
   return no_dubl_lst

print(clean_list([32, 32.1, 32.0, -32, 32, '32']))
```

Result:

```
[32.1, 32, -32, 32.0, '32']
```

But how i can restore original order?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh `{32,32.0,'32'}` will be reduced to `{32,'32'}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try this.

Like you asked *first instance remains in place rest are deleted*.
<sub>(Note that this one is `O(n^2)`)</sub>

```
_list=[32, 32.1, 32.0, -32, 32, '32']
_clist=[]
for i in _list:
    if (i,type(i),) not in _clist:
        _clist.append((i,type(i),))
cleaned_list=list(zip(*_clist))[0]
print(cleaned_list)
#(32, 32.1, 32.0, -32, '32')
```

---

A `O(n)` approach with extra `O(n)` space.

```
_list=[32, 32.1, 32.0, -32, 32, '32']
unique=set()
cleaned=[]
for i in _list:
    if (i,type(i),) not in unique:
        unique.add((i,type(i),))
        cleaned.append(i)
```

Note:

Please check [ivan_pozdeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648265/ivan-pozdeev)'s answer for `timeit` analysis of several answers posted.

Comment: Yes, `O(n^2)` but  can be reduced to `O(N)` if `_clist` is a `set`. But then `cleaned_list` will be unordered. As OP wants order to be preserved `_clist` can't be a set, sadly.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I even posted a `O(N)` approach. Please check the edited answer.

Comment: Still more complicated and fairly slower (my test shows `56ms` vs `44ms` on a `100000` list) than `dict.fromkeys`, but nothing downvote-worthy anymore.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Thanks for the insight and for `timeit` results. Should I tag these `timeit` results? So, it would be helpful for the coming user or you can tag these results in your answer.

Comment: I added timeit results to my answer.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I'll a link to your answer in my answer. So, that upcoming users can see the `timeit` results

Answer (score 4):

There are two concerns here, so for the purpose of an answer, I'll list both.

## Respecting type (you already figured this out)

[Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists) suggests constructing an intermediate `set` as the fastest method. An element is considered to be present in a set if it's equal to a present element.

In your case, you need not just the value, but also the type to be equal.
So why not **construct an intermediate set of tuples `(value, type)`?**

```
unique_list = [v for v,t in {(v,type(v)) for v in orig_list}]
```

## Preserving order

**Use an "ordered set" container** as per [Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set/53657523#53657523). E.g.:

- since 3.7 (and CPython 3.6 where this was an implementation detail), regular `dict`s preserve insertion order:

  ```
  unique_list = [v for v,t in dict.fromkeys((v,type(v)) for v in orig_list)]
  ```
- for all versions <sub>(present in 3.6+, too, because it has additional methods)</sub>, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict):

  ```
  import collections
  unique_list = [v for v,t in collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys((v,type(v)) for v in orig_list)]
  ```

---

For the reference, `timeit` results on my machine (3.7.4 win64) in comparison to other answers as of this writing:

```
In [24]: l=[random.choice((int,float,lambda v:str(int(v))))(random.random()*1000) for _ in range(100000)]

In [26]: timeit dict_fromkeys(l)        #mine
38.6 ms ± 179 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [34]: timeit ordereddict_fromkeys(l)  #mine with OrderedDict
53.3 ms ± 233 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [25]: timeit build_with_filter(l)    #Ch3steR's O(n)
48.7 ms ± 214 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [28]: timeit dict_with_none(l)       #Patrick Artner's
46.8 ms ± 377 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [30]: timeit listcompr_side_effect(l)  #CDJB's
55.5 ms ± 801 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Nice and clever use of `dict.fromkeys`. "Upvoting".

Comment: I can't get it why need to store types separately when standard set() respects types already? Is my answer incorrect?

Comment: @Rugnar `set()` doesn't respect types: `set((32, 32.0)) -> {32}`

Answer (score 3):

The put in set, check set approach is nice. You can also use any `dict()` for python 3.7+ (keys stay input ordered) or an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for python versions below 3.7:

```
def clean_list(list_to_clean):
    ord_dic = dict

    import sys
    major,minor,_,_,_ = sys.version_info

    if major < 3 or major == 3 and minor < 7: 
        # dict not yet input ordered
        from collections import OrderedDict
        no_dubl_lst = OrderedDict(((type(a),a),None) for a in list_to_clean)
    else:
        # dict is input ordered by default
        no_dubl_lst = dict(((type(a),a),None) for a in list_to_clean)


    return list(b for _,b in no_dubl_lst.keys()) # only produce the actual data

print(clean_list([32, 32.1, 32.0, -32, 32, '32']))
```

to produce:

```
[32, 32.1, 32.0, -32, '32']
```

Essentially the dict-keys behave like in a a set (only the first one ever will be used, later ones would overwrite the `None` value of the first one) - but they are ordered.

If you are on 3.7+ simple use

```
def clean_list(list_to_clean):
        # dict is input ordered by default
        no_dubl_lst = dict(((type(a),a),None) for a in list_to_clean)
```

---

Similar to [ivan_pozdeev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59973598/7505395) answer - he deleted/edited/undeleted his first one with more content while I created my answer.

You'll get automatic version detection with mine, so not deleting it.

Comment: Nice answer. Clever use of `dict` properties. Got to know that keys stay in order in Python 3.7+. Always a pleasure reading your answers sir.

Answer (score 0):

My version for this, O(n)

**Edited answer**: now it respects types better then vanilla set

```py
def clean_list(list_to_cealn):
    unique_items = set()
    result = []
    for x in list_to_cealn:
        item = (type(x), x)
        if item not in unique_items:
            result.append(x)
            unique_items.add(item)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/480227/12366110):

```
def clean_list(list_to_clean):
   seen = set()
   seen_add = seen.add
   no_dubl_lst = [value for _, value in [(type(x), x) for x in list_to_clean if not ( (type(x), x) in seen or seen_add((type(x), x)))]]
   return no_dubl_lst

print(clean_list([32, 32.1, 32.0, -32, 32, '32']))
```

Output:

```
[32, 32.1, 32.0, -32, '32']
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a set, keep a `dict` that maps `(x, type(x))` to `x`.

The first time we see `x` of type `y`, it won't be true that `(x,y)` is a key in the dict.

However, there is a functional way to both update a `dict` *and* get the desired value: use the `setdefault` method.

In the following, we first create the tuple (and use `:=` to remember it) and check if it is in `seen` yet. It won't be the first time we encounter `x` of a particular type. Since `t not in seen` is `True`, we'll evaluate the call to `setdefault`. That method call will then return the value of `x`, but as a side effect, also perform `seen[t] = x`. Now, when we find a duplicate, `t not in seen` will return `False`, preventing `seen.setdefault` from being called at all, skipping the duplicate value of `x`. Since we are only iterating over the original input, the original order is preserved in the output.

```
seen = {}
no_dubl_lst = [seen.setdefault(t, x)
               for x in list_to_clean
               if (t:=(x, type(x))) not in seen]
```