# How to move list items to the front if they are in another list while keeping the order

Tags: python

I have a two example lists,

```
vals = ["a", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
xor  = ["c", "g"]
```

I want to sort `vals` list based on the `xor` list,
i.e., the values in `xor` should be placed first in `vals` list in exact order. The rest of the values present in `vals` should stay in the same order.

Also, it is possible that values in `xor` might not be in `vals` in those cases just ignore those values. And also, in the case of duplicates, I only need one value.

Desired output:

```
vals = ["c", "g", "a", "d", "e", "f"]
# here a, d, e, f are not in xor so we keep them in same order as found in vals.
```

My Approach:

```
new_list = []
for x in vals:
    for y in xor:
        if x == y:
            new_list.append(x)
            
for x in vals:
    if x not in xor:
        new_list.append(x)
```

The `vals` list currently has around 800k words or phrases. The `xor` list has 300k words or phrases but it might increase later on. Some phrases are a bit long as well. What would be the most efficient way to address the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build a order dict of indeces in `xor` and use it as a sorting key:

```
order = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(xor)}

sorted(vals, key=lambda x: order.get(x, len(xor)))
# ['c', 'g', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Using `len(vals)` as a default value ensures all values not in `xor` will end up at the back. This of course assumes, that you want the values that *are* in `xor` to be sorted based on their order in `xor` (making the process `O(M+NlogN)`). Otherwise you can be faster (`O(M+N)`) with:

```
from operator import contains
from functools import partial
s = set(xor)
result = list(filter(partial(contains, s), vals))
result.extend(v for v in vals if v not in s)
```

Or in a more readable fashion:

```
s = set(xor)
result = [v for v in vals if v in s]
result += (v for v in vals if v not in s)
```

Comment: What is the time complexity of this approach? I have a huge list.

Comment: `O(M+NlogN)` with `M` the size of `xor` and `N` the size of `vals`.

Comment: I don't want to sort the values in` vals`, other values in vals that are not found in xor should stay in the same order

Comment: Don't use dunder methods like this

Comment: If the second approach is O (M+N), this seems to be more efficient.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wouldn't usually, but given the OP's performance concerns, it does save the repeated method lookup.

Comment: @user_12 Yes, but the values won't be sorted by order within `xor`, as stated. If you don't need that, go for the second variant.

Comment: @schwobaseggl then something like `partial(operator.contains, a))` would be better. I took the liberty of editing

Comment: That's a valid point and appreciated. I am not sure though if that kills the advantage as `partial(operator.contains, s)` might do a plain `in` check under the hood.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Does using partial and contains in any way affect the time?

Comment: @user_12 time it. Actually `.__contains__` might be faster. But it's a bad practice to use dunder methods directly.

Comment: @user_12 For most intents and purposes, we are just nitpicking here. The asymptotic complexity remains unchanged and the differences will be minute.

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes, I'm just triggered by `s.__contains__` hah

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Actually, the first method `s.__contains__` without partial and contains is bit faster.

Comment: @user_12 yes. I assumed as such, but as schwobaseggl stated, this are nitpicks.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Can you provide some comments in the code on how partial and contains work in this case? I am not very familiar with those functions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `len(xor)`?

Comment: @superbrain Of course! I was first going with `len(order)`, but that wouldn't work if there were dupes in `xor`, then made it worse :D

Answer (score 1):

Append all the values from `xor` that exist also in `vals`, with the list of all values of `vals` that do not exist on `xor`:

```
sorted_list = [v for v in xor if v in vals] + [v for v in vals if v not in xor]
```

another approach :

```
output = list(filter(lambda x: x in vals, xor)) + list(filter(lambda x: x not in xor, vals))
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the clarifications added to the question, several of the answers posted here do not actually provide the expected answer, and others are not efficient.

One solution is to take @dreamcrash's answer but using sets for the look-up:

```
def order_by1(vals, xor):
    set_vals = set(vals)
    set_xor = set(xor)
    return [v for v in xor if v in set_vals] + [v for v in vals if v not in set_xor]
```

This should increase efficiency by removing the time-consuming ([O(n)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list)) list lookup on each iteration of the loop.

Since you don't care about the order of the values that are not found in `xor`, a variant of this is to replace the 2nd list comprehension with a set operation:

```
def order_by2(vals, xor):
    set_vals = set(vals)
    return [v for v in xor if v in set_vals] + list(set_vals - set(xor))
```

Another solution is to use [ordered sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)

```
def order_by3(vals, xor):
    vals_set = OrderedSet(vals)
    return (OrderedSet(xor) & vals_set) | vals_set
```

Ordered sets use dictionaries under the hood. We can instead use dictionaries directly, making use of the fact that [they are ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6):

```
def order_by4(vals, xor):
    """ Order list a by each item's position in list xor, if it is found in xor,
        otherwise by its position in list vals """
    d = {k: False for k in xor}
    for k in vals:
        d[k] = True
    return [k for k, v in d.items() if v]
```

The only other solution that actually does what is required is the first one in @schwobaseggl's answer. Timing these with lists of 800,000 and 300,000 random phrases of which 150,000 overlap:

```
import random
import string
import timeit

def random_phrase():
    return "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=10))

def generate_lists(M, N, overlap):
    a = [random_phrase() for _ in range(M)] 
    b = ([random_phrase() for _ in range(N - overlap)] +
          random.sample(a, k=overlap))
    random.shuffle(b)
    return a, b

def dreamcrash(vals, xor):
    return [v for v in xor if v in vals] + [v for v in vals if v not in xor]

def schwobaseggl(vals, xor):
    order = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(xor)}
    len_xor = len(xor)   # saves some time when sorting
    return sorted(vals, key=lambda x: order.get(x, len_xor))

vals, xor = generate_lists(800000, 300000, overlap=150000) # this takes a while
for f in [dreamcrash, order_by1, order_by2, order_by3, order_by4, schwobaseggl]:
    print(f, end='...')
    print(timeit.timeit(stmt=f"{f.__name__}(vals, xor)", number=1, globals=globals()))
```

I gave up on timing `dreamcrash` because it was taking too long. `order_by2` seems fastest, followed by `order_by4`, `order_by1`, and `schwobaseggl`, each taking around .5 - 1.5s on my computer. The ordered set solution is a lot slower. Checking whether a set contains an item, and setting an item in a dictionary, are both [`O(1)` in the average case, `O(n)` in the worst case](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) which explains why the dictionary and set based versions have similar performance.

Comment: What is the time complexity of the second approach?

Comment: Not sure but think it would be similar to ordinary sets - https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity - so O(aM+bN) (a and b depending on overlap between xor and vals) on average, O(MN) worst case. In practice the implementation of ordered sets in python may slow things down.

Comment: See edit for a possibly more efficient algorithm

Comment: Edited again with some performance tests.

Answer (score 0):

This should also be one line solution for you:

```
vals = [1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2, 11, 6]
xor = [10, 11]
new_list = xor + [elem for elem in vals if elem not in xor]
```

(edit: without sorted and correct variables)

Comment: Should be fixed now. It is a matter of simple list generation then.

Comment: From what he states, it is not really clear whether he wants them in the final list or not. Technically you could achieve this with another list generator instead of xor list at the start.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do it with sorting:

```
vals.sort(key=set(xor).__contains__, reverse=True)
```

I suspect it's faster than the others, but don't feel like trying to create test data that might resemble your actual data. (Partly because your question is still not entirely clear. I'm going with what your reference implementation does, i.e., both groups retaining their order in `vals`.)