# Why did the index of my set change when I add the integer 10?

Tags: python, indexing, set

```
print({4, 7, 10})
```

gives as output

```
{10, 4, 7}
```

But I'm working with the indexes of the set.. therefore it's important the order stays the same.
Anyone knows how to prevent this?

```
{4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 17}
```

gives me

```
{17, 4, 7, 10, 11, 12}
```

so it seems that the last item in the set is placed in front. I think it's pretty weird since I didn't say that it needs to happen. I'm just using the print function!

Comment: "But I'm working with the indexes of the set.. therefore it's important the order stays the same." - Python sets do not have indexes or order. If you need a data structure with indexes or order, a set is not going to give you that.

Comment: Maybe some reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set

Comment: Keep the data in a list.  If you need a fast membership test, you can keep *both* a list and a set.  Just remember that removing an arbitrary element from a list will be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements.

Use lists instead, because they keep their order constant.

**References**

[5. Data Structures — Python 3.9.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Answer (score 1):

A set is unordered. Use a list instead!

```
print([10, 7, 4])
#prints [10, 7, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should opt for a list, tuple, or dict