# Randomly prints set elements in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, set

I have 2 lists. One of the is includes string and the other one includes integers. I would like to add two of them to a set, print them in order. But when I try to do so, the set prints randomly in the console. How can I solve this problem?
Here are my arrays,

```
['#', '*']    
[2, 3, 5, 6, 8]
['o', '€']
```

Expected result :

```
 {'#', '*', 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 'o', '€'}
```

But in reality, elements of the set always changes. It never ordered like set updating order. Also, I am using `set_x.update(arr_x)` method to do that.

NOTE: I want to solve this problem without external libs and functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)

Comment: No it doesn't seem like my answer

Comment: What have you tried? Post your attempt here.

Comment: @omeren why does an `OrderedSet` not seem like the answer? How did you try using an `OrderedSet` and why did that not work?

Comment: I have two sets ` s1 = {2,3,5,'*',2,6,'#',3}
s2 = {2,'o',3,5,6,8,'€'}` and i would like to convert them `{'#', '*', 2, 3, 5, 6}, {'#', '*', 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 'o', '€'},
{2, 3, 5, 6}`. I tried that converting them array and i divide the data type 2, integers and strings. I get the integers and strings array.

Comment: @RandomDavis it is not permitted to use external functions or libs. It has to work with pure code.

Comment: @phzdjz this is the first time you've mentioned that; if you have important info like that, it must go into your question. You shouldn't have to follow up in comments with any additional details or restrictions like that.

Comment: @RandomDavis okay thank you, i noted that.

Answer (score 0):

When I do this:

```py
def add_set(a, b, c):
    return set(a + b + c)
add_set(a, b, c)
```

I do have them in the order you requested

Comment: Are you sure that gives the expected result? It certainly doesn't in 3.9.7

Comment: I've tried that like `set1=set(arr_1_str+arr_1_int)
print(set1)` . Here are the results `{2, 3, 5, 6, '*', '#'}` `{2, 3, '*', 5, 6, '#'}`. So order is always changing.

Comment: It's weird, I do have them in the proper order in 3.9.5