# How does Python low-level order sets?

Tags: python, sorting, set

How the sets order the items.
Since it always returns them in the same way.

```
my_set = {45 ,22, 4, 34, 5}
print(my_set)
print(my_set)
print(my_set)
```

and the output is:

```
{34, 4, 5, 22, 45}
{34, 4, 5, 22, 45}
{34, 4, 5, 22, 45}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note that dictionaries and sets are different things. Your question title and content appears to be about sets, not dictionaries.

Comment: I *think* this is what you're asking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set