# Removing an entry from hash table

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm having an issue, where my program is not removing the last given entry from the hash table. My delete function is the following:

```
def delete(self, key):
        if self.size == 0:
            raise Exception("Hash table is empty")
        index = self.find(key)
        if self.table[index] == key:
            self.table[index] = None
            self.size -= 1
```

The given input is `short the decade first employee billion rather five training friend college wear player of in town toward yes last`.
I proceed to remove the following `employee of toward in player town toward five rather yes`
Expected ouput: `short the decade first billion training friend college wear last`
Actual output: `short the decade first billion training friend college wear yes last`
I don't really understand why it removes the other key, but not the last one.

Full code

```
class HashLinear:

    def __init__(self, M):
        self.M = M
        self.table = [None for i in range(M)]
        self.size = 0

    def hash(self, key):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(len(key)):
            sum += ord(key[i])
        return sum % self.M

    def find(self, key):
        index = self.hash(key)
        while self.table[index] != None and self.table[index] != key:
            index = (index + 1) % self.M
        return index

    def insert(self, key):
        if self.size == self.M:
            raise Exception("Hash table is full")
        index = self.find(key)
        if self.table[index] == None:
            self.table[index] = key
            self.size += 1

    def delete(self, key):
        if self.size == 0:
            raise Exception("Hash table is empty")
        index = self.find(key)
        if self.table[index] == key:
            self.table[index] = None
            self.size -= 1

    def print(self):
        for key in self.table:
            if key != None:
                print(key, end=" ")
        print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    table = HashLinear(20)
    table.insert("town")
    table.insert("rather")
    table.insert("short")
    table.insert("toward")
    table.insert("employee")
    table.insert("player")
    table.insert("toward")
    table.insert("the")
    table.insert("of")
    table.insert("college")
    table.insert("in")
    table.insert("yes")
    table.insert("billion")
    table.insert("five")
    table.insert("wear")
    table.insert("last")
    table.insert("decade")
    table.insert("first")
    table.insert("training")
    table.insert("friend")

    table.print()

    table.delete("employee")
    table.delete("of")
    table.delete("toward")
    table.delete("in")
    table.delete("player")
    table.delete("town")
    table.delete("toward")
    table.delete("five")
    table.delete("rather")
    table.delete("yes")

    table.print()
```

Comment: Your `delete` breaks collision resolution.

Answer (score 1):

```
def delete(self, key):
        if self.size == 0:
            raise Exception("Hash table is empty")
        index = self.hash(key)
        if self.table[index] == key:
            self.table[index] = None
            self.size -= 1
        else:
            index = (index + 1) % self.M
            self.table[index] = None
            self.size -= 1
```

Made the trick for me.

Comment: This is completely wrong. It assumes that if a key wasn't found with `find`, it must be in the next hash table cell. That assumption is invalid; the key could be in any cell.

Comment: Open addressing hash tables usually leave a special "deleted entry" marker instead of an "unused cell" marker when they delete entries, so the "find" procedure knows it needs to keep looking when it finds a deleted entry. That avoids the issues your deletion procedure causes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the builtin OrderedDict for OrderedSet (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)):

```
keys = "short the decade first employee billion rather five training friend college wear player of in town toward yes last".split()
keys2 = "employee of toward in player town toward five rather yes".split()

from collections import OrderedDict

S = OrderedDict(zip(keys, [None]*len(keys)))
for k in keys2:
    if k in S:
        S.pop(k)

print(" ".join(S) ) 
# short the decade first billion training friend college wear last
```