# Consolidate a dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df

```
    id  email   firstname   lastname    salutation
    2be858a0458faa569d3d    user_a@gmail.com                Lastname    
    2be858a0458faa569d3d    user_a@gmail.com    Firstname       
    2be858a0458faa569d3d    user_a@gmail.com    Firstname                Mr
```

I want to have a consolidated dataframe df_consolidated

```
    2be858a0458faa569d3d    user_a@gmail.com    Firstname   Lastname Mr
```

The logic should be that it takes all values from df and "sums" them up to one row.

Any idea?

Comment: Empty values are NaN or empty strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby_first`:

```
>>> df.groupby('id', as_index=False).first()

                     id             email  firstname  lastname salutation
0  2be858a0458faa569d3d  user_a@gmail.com  Firstname  Lastname         Mr
```

If empty values are empty strings you can replace `''` by `np.nan` first:

```
>>> df.replace({'': np.nan}).groupby('id', as_index=False).first()

                     id             email  firstname  lastname salutation
0  2be858a0458faa569d3d  user_a@gmail.com  Firstname  Lastname         Mr
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of identifier what is considered the "same".

If all rows are identical and you just want one, you can use:

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

or the answer of @Corralien.

If all rows which should be aggregated share a specific trait, e.g. 'id' you can use:

```
df.groupby(['id']).apply(set)
```

which will return 1 row and a set of unique values for each id and column.
A set in python is unordered, so if the order matters you can use the keys of a dictionary as a replacement, see here:
[Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)