# Time complexity of dict.fromkeys()

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to get an ordered set in Python 3.8. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657523/13679903), I'm using `dict.fromkeys()` method to get the unique items from a list preserving the insertion order. What's the time complexity of this method? As I'm using this frequently in my codebase, is it the most efficient way or is there any better way to get an ordered set?

```
>>> lst = [4,2,4,5,6,2]
>>> dict.fromkeys(lst)
{4: None, 2: None, 5: None, 6: None}
>>> list(dict.fromkeys(lst))
[4, 2, 5, 6]
```

Comment: [Python complexity cheat sheet](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/complexity-cheat-sheet-for-python-operations/)

Comment: Inserting into a dictionary is amortized O(1). Iterating over the list is O(n).

Comment: I suspect this is the best you can do. `dict.fromkeys()` should be implemented in optimized C code, so any loop in Python is likely to be worse.