# How to put inputted item first in list CS50 python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, cs50

Here is my code. when I input (a, b, a), it outputs (1 b, 2 a). but in my input I put the "a" first.
My expected output is (2a, 1b). so why is my code not working according to plan.

```py
    def main():
        ml = []
        x = 0
        grocery(ml)
        for i in set(ml):
            x = ml.count(i)
            if x == 1:
                print(x, i)
            else:
                print(x, i)
                for _ in range(x):
                    ml.remove(i)
    
    def grocery(ml):
        while True:
            try:
                x = input("").upper().strip()
                ml.append(x)
            except (KeyError, AttributeError):
                pass
            except EOFError:
                return ml
    
    
    main()
```

Comment: Python `set()` is unordered (see: `for i in set(ml)`). You might want to look at using a solution based on a `dict` instead where key order is preserved. You also might want to check out `collections.Counter()`.

Comment: check out : [Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is the `set()` function.

> The `set()` function creates a set object. The items in a set list are unordered, so it will appear in random order.
> [set()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_set.asp)

You can use ```OrderedDict() to remember the order in which dictionary keys were first inserted.

> An OrderedDict is a dictionary subclass that remembers the order in which keys were first inserted. The only difference between dict() and OrderedDict() lies in their handling of key order in Python. OrderedDict vs dict in Python
> `OrderedDict` maintains the sequence in which keys are added, ensuring that the order is preserved during iteration. In contrast, a standard dictionary does not guarantee any specific order when iterated, providing values in an arbitrary sequence. `OrderedDict` distinguishes itself by retaining the original insertion order of items. [OrderedDict in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordereddict-in-python/)

Code fixed:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def main():
    ml = []
    grocery(ml)
    
    # Use OrderedDict to maintain the order
    counts = OrderedDict()
    for item in ml:
        if item in counts:
            counts[item] += 1
        else:
            counts[item] = 1

    # Print the counts in the order they were first entered
    for item, count in counts.items():
        print(count, item)

def grocery(ml):
    while True:
        try:
            x = input("").upper().strip()
            ml.append(x)
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            pass
        except EOFError:
            return ml

main()
```